# HTML tags in i18next translation

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I'm using [i18next](http://i18next.com/) to power i18n for my weblog.  It works great on text-only content, but when I try to translate content that includes HTML markup, it is displaying the raw markup when I translate the text.

As an example, here is a snippet of the markup from a post that is not working as expected:

```
<div class="i18n" data-i18n="content.body">
  In Medellín they have many different types of <i>jugos naturales</i>&nbsp;(fruit juice) ... <br />
  <br />
  ...
</div>
```

The translation code looks like this:

```
var resources = {
  "en": ...,
  "es": {
    "translation": {
      "content": {
        "body": "En Medellín hay varios tipos diferentes de <i>jugos naturales</i> ... <br /><br /> ... "
      }
    }
  }
}

i18n.init({"resStore": resources}, function( t ) {
  $('.i18n').i18n();
});
```

When the translation is rendered, HTML tags are escaped and output as text:

```
En Medellín hay varios tipos diferentes de &lt;i&gt;jugos naturales&lt;/i&gt;...&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
```

How do I get i18next to change the HTML of translated elements?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In order to make this work, you have to prefix the `data-i18n` attribute of the elements you want to translate with `[html]`:

```
<div class="i18n" data-i18n="[html]content.body">
```

Source:  [i18next.jquery.js](https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/blob/1.7.2/src/i18next.jquery.js#L21)

Comment: @user212218 I tried this, but it is not working for me.

I am using a plain HTML file and loading translation JSON files using i18n.load function in javascript.

I am trying to use an HTML tag in one of the headings of the page.

JSON:
`"abc" : "hi <h2 class=\"header-class\">I am trying<\/h2> to use"`

html:
`<span data-i18n="[html]abc" class="span-class"></span>`

What am I missing? The above displays `[html]abc` in browser

Comment: Correct solution! I did have to play a bit. This example may help: (1) in js code: <span data-i18n='[html]_error_date_invalid'>_error_date_invalid</span> and (2) in i18n json: "_error_date_invalid": "<b>This date is not valid</b>.<BR>Please make sure that the date is between tomorrow and one year after now"

Comment: There is a newer guide for jquery-i18next here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3

Comment: also stated in the official docs: https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#set-innerhtml-attributes

Answer (score 42):

For anyone trying to do this in **React** (for example with `react-i18-next`), be aware that React *also* escapes the string!  So we have to tell *both* i18n and React not to escape the string.

- To tell i18n to skip escaping, we use `{escapeValue: false}` as others have shown.
- To tell React to skip escaping, we use React's [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/189#issuecomment-234870445) attribute.

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
    {__html: t('foo', {interpolation: {escapeValue: false}})}
} />
```

That attribute accepts an object with one property `__html`.  React intentionally made it ugly, to discourage its use, because not escaping can be dangerous.

For security, raw user input should not be used inside this element.  If you do need to use an untrusted string here, be sure to sanitise or escape it, so the user cannot inject raw `<` or `>` into the page.

Comment: Be careful when using **any user-input** because of potential XSS-attacks. I just wanted to use HTML-tags in the translation therefore I went with `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
    {__html: t('foo', {interpolation: {escapeValue: true}})}
} />`

Answer (score 29):

You need to turn off escaping:

`i18n.t("key", { 'interpolation': {'escapeValue': false} })`

Comment: For anyone **trying to do this in React** with react-i18-next, beware that React also escapes the string! To tell React to not escape the string, we must use React's ugly [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/189#issuecomment-234870445) technique: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('foo')}} />`

Comment: @joeytwiddle this ugly technique will make you aware of the security risk that comes with the technique. If it was a clean solution you may copy past and use it without knowing there is a downside with the technic ;)

Answer (score 14):

> This is an answer for React.

Eventually found a straight forward solution that can make code easier to maintain. Hope this helps!

```
{
  "stackoverflow": "<site_anchor>Welcome to stackoverflow!</site_anchor> You can also <profile_anchor>check my profile</profile_anchor>" 
}
```

```
import {Trans} from "react-i18next";
```

```
<Trans i18nKey="stackoverflow" components={{
  site_anchor: <Link href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank"/>,
  profile_anchor: <Link href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/18131146/mondayrris" target="_blank"/>,
}} />
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't put the HTML tags in the translation. It's a bad idea anyway. *Separation of concerns* guys will be all whiny about it.

Use the `<Trans>` component if **react-i18next** [https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component][1]

Do like so:

```js
// Component.js

<Trans>Welcome, <strong>User!</strong>, here's your <strong>broom</strong></Trans>
```

And the corresponding translation file:

```js
// your locales/starwars_en.js file

translations: {
  "Welcome, <1>User!</1>, here's your <3>broom</3>": "Welcome, <1>young padawan!</1>, here's your <3>light saber</3>",
}
```

These numbers *<1>* and *<3>* will strike you as random but wait for it:

```js
Trans.children = [
  'Welcome, ',                        // index 0
  '<strong>User!</strong>'            // index 1
  ', please don't be ',               // index 2
  '<strong>weak</strong>',            // index 3
  ' unread messages. ',               // index 4
]
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563302/537648

Comment: What am I missing here? It seems like with this solution you are now stuck with having hard coded English translations in Component.js.

Comment: Yep. English as a base language. It's a bit hacky but saves time in our case.

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](http://i18next.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_features.html):

> Hint 3: Escaping:
>
> ```
> // given resources
> {           
>   'en-US': { 
>     translation: { 
>       key1: Not escaped __nameHTML__,
>       key2: Escaped __name__ 
>     } 
>   }
> };
>
> i18n.t("key2", { name: '', escapeInterpolation: true }); // -> Escaped &lt;tag&gt;
> i18n.t("key1", { name: '', escapeInterpolation: false }); // -> Not escaped <tag>
> ```
>
> Adding suffix 'HTML__' to your value will prevent the escaping even if
>   option is set so.
>
> You could turn on escaping on init `i18n.init({escapeInterpolation:
>   true});` or by passing in option to t function like in the sample.

Answer (score 7):

`i18n.t('key',{dateStr: date, interpolation: {escapeValue: false}})`

worked for me if `date='15/10/2020'`, slashes were kept as well

Comment: but the html is still escaped, i wonder did you do other setting for the html to not be escaped ?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the escaping during initialization globally:

```js
i18n.init({
  // ...
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that this may lead to unexpected security issues being introduced (namely XSS), if you are rendering user input somewhere in your application.

Comment: @FanaticD Only if you use `innerHTML = ...` which is unsafe anyway

Answer (score 1):

For `React` apps using `react-i18next` package `v11.6^` you can use `Trans` component in a smoothy way to apply html tags along with the translation text, I'll put this in a simple example:

inside our text translations file we have:

```js
 greetings: 'Hello {{name}}!'
```

and we want to apply bold style on name variable using html tag `strong`, to do so we can:

```js
 greetings: 'Hello <0>{{name}}</0>!'
```

Then where we want to use the translation we import `Trans` component from `react-i18next` and use it like so:

```js
<Trans
 i18nKey='greetings'
 values={{
  name: 'John'
 }}
 components={[<strong />]}
/>
```

Then the result will be: Hello **John**!

Check here for more info: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both React and React Native. For the React app The solution works. Not for React Native.

**React**
i18n.js

```
interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false   
    }
```

somefile.jsx

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('dropZone.description')}} />
```

**React Native**
This solution does not work because < div> is not allowed within a Text tag. I tried to add the dangerouslySetInnerHTML to the Text tag, but then nothing is visible.

Does someone have a solution for React Native?

Comment: for React Native you can use String.fromCharCode method:
const nonBreakingString = `My Custom String${String.fromCharCode(160)}5`

Answer (score 0):

I was need use only bold text. So I used this code:

```
<Trans i18nKey='translationKey' values={{ name: 'ANY_VALUE' }} />
```

TranslationKey -> `Do you want to remove <strong>{{name}}</strong> ...?`
Found this solution in [i18n documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for React components as per [the docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component) is:

```
// Component.jsx

<Trans i18nKey="newProfileLink">
    <Link to='/profile/new'>linkPlaceholder</Link>
</Trans>

// translations.js

{
"newProfileLink": "<0>Click here</0> to create a profile."
}
```

Note: the `<0>` refers to the index of the children passed to the `Trans` component. You can easily see the children and their corresponding index by looking at the `props` passed to the `Trans` component in developer tools.

Answer (score -1):

Solution in ReactJS:

Initial component:

```
...
<Typography>Hello <b>World</b><br />This is an <strong>example</strong></Typography>
...
```

Using [Interweave](https://interweave.dev/docs/) with [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)

```
...
import { Markup } from "interweave"
...
<Typography><Markup content={t("paragraph")} /></Typography>
...
```

And your en.json file:

```json
{
 "paragraph": "Hello <b>World</b><br />This is an <strong>example</strong>"
}
```

es.json:

```json
{
 "paragraph": "Hola <b>Mundo</b><br />Esto es un <strong>ejemplo</strong>"
}
```

More information: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159227/17717225)