# ReactJS convert HTML string to JSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm having trouble dealing with facebook's ReactJS. Whenever I do ajax and want to display an html data, ReactJS displays it as text. (See figure below)

[image: ReactJS render string]

The data is displayed through the success callback function of the jquery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url here,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      this.setState({
           action: data.action
      })
   }.bind(this)
});
```

[image]

Is there any easy way to convert this into html? How should I do it using ReactJS?

Comment: You can view my answer here - w/o using dangerouslySetInnerHTML https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626638/10816972

Answer (score 531, accepted):

By default, React escapes the HTML to prevent [XSS (Cross-site scripting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). If you really want to render HTML, you can use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property:

```
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.actions}} />
```

React forces this intentionally-cumbersome syntax so that you don't accidentally render text as HTML and introduce XSS bugs.

Comment: This syntax is shown on the homepage and in the tutorial, but I just realized it's not documented anywhere else so I just filed [#413](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/413) to fix.

Comment: Correct! I've solved this already using dangerouslySetInnerHTML but thanks though :)

Comment: It's worth playing it safe to sanitize the content using the `sanitize` function from the `dompurify` npm package if you're getting that information from an external API.

Comment: Note that despite it being 'dangerous' if you are merely using it to render html from your server it's no more dangerous than displaying that content in a webpage.  The danger arises if that content has user provided input that hasn't been sanitized and if it's direct from the server you should have already sanitized in back end.

Comment: You can try the easiest solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx/65022192#65022192

Answer (score 93):

There are now safer methods to accomplish this. The [docs have been updated](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html) with these methods.

**Other Methods**

1. **Easiest** - Use Unicode, save the file as UTF-8 and set the `charset` to UTF-8.

   `<div>{'First · Second'}</div>`
2. **Safer** - Use the Unicode number for the entity inside a Javascript string.

   `<div>{'First \u00b7 Second'}</div>`

   or

   `<div>{'First ' + String.fromCharCode(183) + ' Second'}</div>`
3. Or a mixed array with strings and JSX elements.

   `<div>{['First ', <span>&middot;</span>, ' Second']}</div>`
4. **Last Resort** - Insert raw HTML using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

   `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}} />`

Comment: I've ready the documentation but about a long HTML string such as one from a WYSIWYG editor? I can't see how we can use the 1st, 2nd or 3rd method

Comment: I agree with @eric. What good are methods 1-3 for already escaped content stored somewhere, e.g. a DB? Also note that method 4 – the only method – means you can't add child nodes.

Comment: Yup. These examples with hard-coded "dynamic" content don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is my innerHTML - "Displaying admins \u003cb\u003e1\u0026nbsp;-\u0026nbsp;10\u003c/b\u003e of \u003cb\u003e13\u003c/b\u003e in total" while this is what is being rendered - "Displaying admins <b>1&nbsp;-&nbsp;10</b> of <b>13</b> in total". When I try to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, evrything breaks.

Answer (score 68):

I recommend using [Interweave](https://github.com/milesj/interweave) created by [milesj](https://github.com/milesj). Its a phenomenal library that makes use of a number if ingenious techniques to parse and safely insert HTML into the DOM.

> Interweave is a react library to safely render HTML, filter
>   attributes, autowrap text with matchers, render emoji characters, and
>   much more.

- **Interweave is a robust React library that can:**

  - Safely render HTML without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
  - Safely strip HTML tags.
  - Automatic XSS and injection protection.
  - Clean HTML attributes using filters.
  - Interpolate components using matchers.
  - Autolink URLs, IPs, emails, and hashtags.
  - Render Emoji and emoticon characters.
  - And much more!

**Usage Example:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Markup } from 'interweave';

const articleContent = "<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor laboriosam.</b> </p><p>Facere debitis impedit doloremque eveniet eligendi reiciendis <u>ratione obcaecati repellendus</u> culpa? Blanditiis enim cum tenetur non rem, atque, earum quis, reprehenderit accusantium iure quas beatae.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href='#testLink'>this is a link, click me</a> Sunt ducimus corrupti? Eveniet velit numquam deleniti, delectus  <ol><li>reiciendis ratione obcaecati</li><li>repellendus culpa? Blanditiis enim</li><li>cum tenetur non rem, atque, earum quis,</li></ol>reprehenderit accusantium iure quas beatae.</p>"

<Markup content={articleContent} /> // this will take the articleContent string and convert it to HTML markup. See: https://milesj.gitbook.io/interweave


//to install package using npm, execute the command
npm install interweave
```

Comment: Could you provide a usage example please?

Comment: @ElAnonimo I have added a usage example. Hope that makes things a bit more clearer.

Comment: Thanks a million, interweave is exactly what I needed. Cheers.

Comment: The documentation for this is not helpful. Also I tried out with few lines of html and I had a page full of error messages. Do someone have examples or any resources with documentation?

Comment: Do you know what threats Interweave does NOT cover?

Comment: Interweave works great for us.  Thanks for the rec!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981011/interweave-library-and-react

I asked this question, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 31):

```
npm i html-react-parser;

import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

<td>{Parser(this.state.archyves)}</td>
```

Comment: The latest version of this library provides a very clean way of injecting html. And the `replace` method is a great way to replace (for example) `img` tags with your own `<Image/>` components.

Answer (score 14):

For those still experimenting, npm install react-html-parser

When I installed it it had 123628 weekly downloads.

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'

<div>{ReactHtmlParser(htmlString)}</div>
```

Comment: FYI this library isn't maintained, as per the recent activity history

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following if you want to render raw html in React

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `html-raw-goes-here`}} />
```

Example - Render

**Test** is a good day

Answer (score 8):

This could have been solved by using the content put inside this block `{[]}` like this. Example could be referred below for better clarity.

```
{[
   'abc',
   <b>my bold</b>, 
   'some other text'
]}
```

This would preserve the formatting for text under tags while the others would be printed as plain text.

Answer (score 6):

i found this js fiddle. this works like this

```
function unescapeHTML(html) {
    var escapeEl = document.createElement('textarea');
    escapeEl.innerHTML = html;
    return escapeEl.textContent;
}

<textarea className="form-control redactor"
                          rows="5" cols="9"
                          defaultValue={unescapeHTML(this.props.destination.description)}
                          name='description'></textarea>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/qPUEX/) link

Comment: Unfortunately document doesn't work on server rendering.

Comment: It might if you do `import JSDOM from 'jsdom'; 
 global.window = new JSDOM('', { url: 'http://localhost' });
 global.document = global.window.document;` idk goodluck

Comment: And where is the JSX?

Answer (score 5):

i start using npm package called react-html-parser

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Parser() from html-react-parser. 
I have used the same. [Link](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) shared.

Answer (score 4):

One option that's missing in the existing answers is using [`<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (*available in React v16 and later*). I find this best because this allows you to **store any html element as a JSX variable** and refer to it later. Also because using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not secure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380982/6908282).

For Example

```js
const App = () => {
    const Windows = <React.Fragment>Microsoft <abbr title="Operating System">OS</abbr></React.Fragment>

    return (
      <ul>
        <li>{Windows}</li>
      </ul>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### Other alternatives and considerations:

1. If you're fetching the HTML from external sources, then you cannot use this approach because the fetched HTML will be in a string format. In that case you need to parse the HTML using a HTML Parser like [html-react-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617112/6908282)
2. If you don't have any keys or attributes, [you can also use `<></>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194678/6908282) which is a shorthand for `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`
3. Keep in mind that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` [is dangerous to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380982/6908282) because malicious client side code can be injected via script tags:
4. @Brett has also suggested [other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938353/6908282):
5. **Note:** using quotes in a JSX Variale

   - You should not surround a JSX variable with quotes (*like a regular variable*) - you should surround it with `<React.Fragment> </ React.Fragment>`
   - you should not escape quotes in a html tag of a JSX variable - for example the `title` in `<abbr />` tag above has quotes which are not escaped.

Comment: const samplehtml = "<h1>Microsoft <abbr title=\"Operating System\">OS</abbr></h1>"
  const Windows = <React.Fragment>{samplehtml}</React.Fragment>
This is not working

Comment: even `samplehtml` is a JSX variable, so you need to enclose that with `<React.Fragment>` as well - like this: `const samplehtml = <React.Fragment><h1>Microsoft <abbr title="Operating System">OS</abbr></h1></React.Fragment>`

Comment: I made suggested changes but still html is rendered as string

Comment: you probably have a syntax error. You should not surround a JSX variable with quotes and you should not escape quotes in your`<abbr />` tag as well. Copy the `samplehtml` variable from above comment.

Comment: samplehtml is html coming from database so it is surrounded by quotes
I want convert htmlstring coming from database to jsx

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323189/6908282

Comment: Actually, your use case needs a different approach - since you're fetching the HTML from a database, you need to parse it either using a [HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617112/6908282) or use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Actually I didn't want use other libraries , Using react API is there any way to parse html string to React JSX?

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is danger so thats my last resort

Comment: I am getting Blog content from Database putting it inside span may effect SEO

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of any other way. Also you have concerns are not exactly related to this question. So I suggest you to post a new question mentioning all you concerns which would get the right folks to provide you an answer.

Comment: Actually I am in correct question- [ReactJS convert HTML string to JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx),
that is what I want converting html in string to JSX

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead what tags are in the string you want to render; this could be for example if only certain tags are allowed in the moment of the creation of the string; a possible way to address this is use the Trans utility:

```
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next'
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

export type MyComponentProps = {
    htmlString: string
}

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = ({
  htmlString
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Trans
        components={{
          b: <b />,
          p: <p />
        }}
      >
        {htmlString}
      </Trans>
    </div>
  )
}
```

then you can use it as always

```
<MyComponent
    htmlString={'<p>Hello <b>World</b></p>'}
/>
```