# Insert HTML with React Variable Statements (JSX)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building something with React where I need to insert HTML with React Variables in JSX. Is there a way to have a variable like so:

```
var thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>';
```

and to insert it into react like so, and have it work?

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content">{thisIsMyCopy}</div>
    );
}
```

and have it insert the HTML as expected? I haven't seen or heard anything about a react function that could do this inline, or a method of parsing things that would allow this to work.

Answer (score 437, accepted):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html), e.g.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: thisIsMyCopy}}></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: How does this work if you need to add something to `<head>`?

Comment: Normal DOM methods in componentDidMount should work, I've not done it before though.

Comment: @DanielleMadeley Are you trying to insert conditional IE comments into <head>? If so, I've had success using the trick described here: https://nemisj.com/conditional-ie-comments-in-react-js/

Comment: @CamJackson I'm trying to insert a beacon header provided by New Relic.

Comment: Make sure you pass a method to the dangerouslySetInnerHTML and not a hash. According to the docs, it's dangerous to just pass a hash. Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: @DanielleMadeley Helmet is a library for that: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: Is there a way without inserting the div?

Comment: how to refresh this html content?

Answer (score 153):

**Note that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can be dangerous if you do not know what is in the HTML string you are injecting.** This is because malicious client side code can be injected via script tags.

It is probably a good idea to sanitize the HTML string via a utility such as **[DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)** if you are not 100% sure the HTML you are rendering is XSS (cross-site scripting) safe.

Example:

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'

const thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>';


render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(thisIsMyCopy)}}></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: @vsync nope it shouldn't :)

Comment: is it possible to render not only html tags but tag from library like material ui Alert tag. i want the code to be like this `import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'

const thisIsMyCopy = '<Alert severity="warning">copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></Alert >';


render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(thisIsMyCopy)}}></div>
    );
}`

Comment: @sasharomanov, Did you get any solution for this scenario ?

Answer (score 79):

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html) has many disadvantage because it set inside the tag.

I suggest you to use some react wrapper like i found one here on npm for this purpose.
[html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) does the same job.

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
var thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>';


render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content">{Parser(thisIsMyCopy)}</div>
    );
}
```

Very Simple :)

**UPDATE**

in the [latest version](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) as usage explained:

```
// ES Modules
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

// CommonJS
const parse = require('html-react-parser');
....

//Parse single element
parse('<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li>');

//Parse multiple elements
parse('<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li>');
```

Comment: "dangerouslySetInnerHTML has many disadvantage because it set inside the tag." Can you explain more about this. Trying to think out what fundamental difference there is between html-react-parser and sanatized innerHtml

Comment: It seems that html-react-parser doesn't sanitize the input - see the FAQ

Answer (score 62):

By using `''` you are making it to a string. Use without inverted commas it will work fine.

```js
const App = () => {
const span = <span> whatever your string </span>

const dynamicString = "Hehe";
const dynamicStringSpan = <span> {`${dynamicString}`} </span>

  return (
    <div>

      {span}

      {dynamicStringSpan}

    </div>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: By far the simplest answer especially if the HTML is written by you and dynamic based on user input.  You can quite literally set var myHtml = <p>Some text</p>; and it works

Comment: I thought it would be for a dynamically generated string (e.g. from user generated content) where your solution would not work. But thanks!

Comment: This only works for wrapped strings. You couldn't for instance ad a <br /> tag to the text so this solution does not answer the question.

Answer (score 9):

```
import { Fragment } from 'react' // react version > 16.0

var thisIsMyCopy = (
  <Fragment>
    <p>copy copy copy&nbsp;
    <strong>strong copy</strong>
    </p>
  </Fragment>
)
```

By using '' the sets the value to a string and React has no way of knowing that it is a HTML element. You can do the following to let React know it is a HTML element -

1. Remove the `''` and it would work
2. Use `<Fragment>` to return a HTML element.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The content of ``thisIsMyCopy`` is itself JSX, not a string of HTML. So you're literally pasting JSX into JSX.

Comment: You can find Fragments in the Preact too but only in version X and on.

Comment: I think this is the best way because we don't have to store it as a string variable with this approach. Also keep in mind that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is dangerous to use because malicious client side code can be injected via script tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380982/6908282

Answer (score 8):

To avoid linter errors, I use it like this:

```
  render() {
    const props = {
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: '<br/>' },
    };
    return (
        <div {...props}></div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any special library or "dangerous" attribute. You can just use React Refs to manipulate the DOM:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props);       
        this.divRef = React.createRef();
        this.myHTML = "<p>Hello World!</p>"
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        
        this.divRef.current.innerHTML = this.myHTML;
    }
    
    render() {
        
        return (
            
            <div ref={this.divRef}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

A working sample can be found here:

https://codepen.io/bemipefe/pen/mdEjaMK

Comment: Good one, and you can even use `this.divRef.current.outerHTML = this.myHTML;` to avoid the extra `div`. However, `createRef` requires React 16.3, that is not always an option, for instance with SPFx for SharePoint 2019 on-prem...

Answer (score 2):

Try [Fragment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fragment), if you don't want any of above.

In your case, we can write

```
import React, {useState, Fragment} from 'react'

const thisIsMyCopy = Fragment('<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>')

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content">{thisIsMyCopy}</div>
    );
}
```

If you using hook want to set it in a state somewhere with any condition

```
const [thisIsMyCopy, setThisIsMyCopy] = useState(<Fragment><p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p></Fragment>);
```

Comment: The library you are referencing is not part of React, but in your code you're importing Fragment from React. Your snippet throws an error.

Comment: the link you provided shows that it is fragment with a lowercase f and does not show where you are importing it from.

Answer (score -4):

If anyone else still lands here. With ES6 you can create your html variable like so:

```
render(){
    var thisIsMyCopy = (
        <p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>
    );
    return(
        <div>
            {thisIsMyCopy}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: and if you want variables inside your string, you'll need to wrap each in `{}` and the whole string in some markup like so `(<span>{telephoneNumber} <br /> {email}</span>)`

Comment: This is different from what's asked in the question. In the question `<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>` is a string. You have it as JSX.

Comment: That is not ES6, but JSX

Answer (score -6):

You can also include this HTML in ReactDOM like this:

```
var thisIsMyCopy = (<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>);

ReactDOM.render(<div className="content">{thisIsMyCopy}</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here are two links [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) and [link2](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) from React documentation which could be helpful.