# Render HTML tags properly in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have to create a text module in React, i'm using JSX too; I will receive the data from a JSON file. For example:

`{ "text-data": 
      "text": "<small> Hello world </small>"
 }`

I tried to do something like this in my module:
    `<p> {this.props.textData.text}</p>`

When I try to render this in my JSX file, it show as plain text with the tags included. I've been researching and I found that I could use this function "Dangerously Set innerHTML"  but it's not recommended because it can cause an XSS attack. I read here other answers about this, that say that using HTML entities work; but I can't make that work for now.

Comment: Can you provide more information and the relevant code. It is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** prop is there for cases like this. In effect, you're saying that you *completely* trust the html that you're outputting and that it's valid html. You would not want to use it for user input (unless absolutely necessary and thoroughly validated).

See the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) for more information. There is also a previous similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I know that there are similar questions, sorry.

Comment: This is still a valid issue and I'm not so sure the "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" prop is the answer for the security reasons cited above.  The situation where I find the need for it is with "/" in text where you need to inject a dynamic <wbr> element.