# How I inject HTML with classes received from an API into React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a large React project where we are receiving data from an API we don't control  Occasionally we need to receive an HTML string with inline styles and insert all of it directly in our component.  It will be passed to us as a string -- I've not gotten a clear answer from the backend team, but I think it will be something like

`<textarea rows='1' cols'50' >Some text with <span class='special style'>special styles applied</span></textarea>`

How do I insert this into my react component correctly (and safely)?  Simply something like the following?

```
const myHTMLStringFromAPI = getApiStuff()

  render(){
  return <div>{myHTMLStringFromAPI}</div>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML with React Variable Statements (JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx)

Comment: It seems it is a duplicate.  Should I just close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

> **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** is React’s replacement for using **innerHTML** in the browser DOM. This is used because setting `innerHTML` directly is risky.

```
const myHTMLStringFromAPI = getApiStuff()
  render(){
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:`<textarea rows='1' cols'50' >Some text with <span class='special style'>special styles applied</span></textarea>`}}>{myHTMLStringFromAPI}</div>
}
```