# Add jsx in value of key hooks react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my code

```
const events = [
    {
      event_name: 'Movie Night',
      event_image: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=?????????????????',
      event_date: 'Feb 29',
      event_day: 'Friday',
      event_time: '6:30 PM – 9:30 PM',
      event_description:
        'In partnership with our Building, we present Movie Night!'
    }
  ]
```

but i would like to add styling to the description hence, adding jsx to the value of the key, something like this

```
event_description: 'In partnership with our <span className="font-bold> "Building </span>, we present Movie Night!'
```

**btw, i'm using *tailwind***

but my syntax is not accepted, *nor the others that i tried*, if anyone could help on how this should be done it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an inline component for the case where you need to add some styles.

For your case you can do the following.

```js
const events = [
    {
        event_name: 'Movie Night',
        event_image: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=?????????????????',
        event_date: 'Feb 29',
        event_day: 'Friday',
        event_time: '6:30 PM – 9:30 PM',
        event_description: () => (<>In partnership with our <span className='font-bold'>Building </span>, we present Movie Night!</>)
    }
];
```

while rendering you can do something like-

```js
return events[0].event_description()
```

You can also use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. However it is not recommended as per react offical docs.

[Insert HTML with React Variable Statements (JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx)

you can also use some libraries for ex: `html-react-parser`