# How to convert JSON to Html in a React App

Tags: reactjs

How to convert JSON to normal html with html elements in a react app?

**Note that dangerouslySetInnerHTML can be dangerous if you do not know what is in the HTML string you are injecting**

According to react docs -

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
> the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
> it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
> (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
> to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
> key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

I have created a code sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sunset-tlmr2?file=/src/App.js

The output just renders as string instead of html elements.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const blocks = {
  time: 1602725895949,
  blocks: [
    {
      type: "header",
      data: {
        text: "This is a heading",
        level: 2
      }
    },
    {
      type: "paragraph",
      data: {
        text: "This is a paragraph"
      }
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  function convertToHtml({ blocks }) {
    console.log(blocks);
    var convertedHtml = "";
    blocks.map((block) => {
      switch (block.type) {
        case "header":
          convertedHtml += `<h${block.data.level}>${block.data.text}</h${block.data.level}>`;
          break;
        case "paragraph":
          convertedHtml += `<p>${block.data.text}</p>`;
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Unknown block type", block.type);
          break;
      }
    });

    return <React.Fragment>{convertedHtml}</React.Fragment>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>JSON to html below</h1>
      {convertToHtml(blocks)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert HTML with React Variable Statements (JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx)

Comment: You have to return the JSX directly instead of making it a string.  I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @diedu I edited the question to show that dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not recommended according to react docs. The answer you posted uses dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are generating HTML in React you don't want to treat it as a string, you want to treat it as components.  Instead of returning a literal string `'<p>${block.data.text}</p>'` you can return `<p>{block.data.text}</p>` which is valid JSX.

I've converted your switch statement into a function component which renders a single block.  Note that `null` is the standard return for a component which doesn't render anything.  For the case where you are making `h1`, `h2`, etc. dynamically, I saved that string as a capital letter variable so that React interprets it as a custom component instead of a built-in element.

```
export function Block({ type, data }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "header":
      const Element = "h" + data.level;
      return <Element>{data.text}</Element>;
    case "paragraph":
      return <p>{data.text}</p>;
    default:
      console.log("Unknown block type", type);
      return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can loop through the array of blocks and pass each block off as props to the `Block` component. Whenever you return elements from a loop, react throws a warning if you don't set a `key`, so I am using the array index as the key.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>JSON to html below</h1>
      {blocks.blocks.map((block, i) => (
        <Block key={i} {...block} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-blocks-8oiqr?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3):

I have another answer.

Try this one. Now without dangerously HTML stuff.

```js
import parse from "html-react-parser";

return <React.Fragment>{parse(convertedHtml)}</React.Fragment>;
```

Package: https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/html-react-parser

The same `Code Sandbox`

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glitter-1nnkc?file=/src/App.js:27-65

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I really try to avoid installing more packages as much as possible. I am hoping there might be a jsx way of doing this.

Comment: You can instead of concatenating string use ``React.createElement('div', {}, 'text')``

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Like this:

```js
return <React.Fragment>{<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: convertedHtml }} />}</React.Fragment>;
```

I also forked your `Code Sandbox` with the solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glitter-1nnkc?file=/src/App.js:1542-1674

**Mark as answer if it works**.
Thanks

Comment: According to react docs, this is not a good practice -  easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.