# Inject external HTML/JS in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I'm doing a little web app using React Typescript and I have one problem I'm unable to fix.

My app obtains from an external API (using a POST request) a plotly graph in text/html. What I need to do is to inject this HTML and JS in my React App in order to be displayed in the browser.

What is the best way to do this? I've tried different approaches and nothing seems to work. I think the HTML components are being rendered, but the JS isn't being executed.

I need to inject something using this structure. The code bellow is not completed.

```
<div>
<div id="div-1" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%, width:100%">
Plotly.newPlot("div-1",...)
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx

Comment: That's the solution I'm currently using. However, the JS is not executed.

Comment: can you add the HTML and CSS responses in the question as well

Comment: The problem lies within the JS code not being executed.
At list I think the parent divs render properly.

Answer (score 1):

try loading the html dynamically then.

```js
const divElement = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  if (divElement.current)
    divElement.current.innerHTML = "Your html and js will be executed"
}, [])

return ( <
  div className = "test"
  ref = {divElement}>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I'm using functional components within React Typecsript, I'm unable to do that.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a functional components. Have a look

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However when I tried that, the problem persists. The parent divs are rendered, but the plotly.js Javascript inside isn't executed.

Comment: This should have worked, then it is something to do with your js file

Comment: For example.  Your code injects the HTML correctly. But if I try to do something like this `divElement.current.innerHTML = '<div><script>console.log("Hello world!")</script></div>';` when I open my console i don't see any console.log. In other words, the js isn't being executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try alert instead of console, this should make thing easer to confirm