# What is correct way of passing html tags in React State?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am in process of creating Blog using React. I am planning to bring main content of blog from server and passed to React Component via Props/State. Blog content can have html tags like :

- blockquote
- h2 and h3
- img, Video, embed code etc etc

I was hoping to store content of blog in Database/json files along with these tags and render the content as it is on page load.
But It seems to be difficult to do it in React. There are three ways we can achieve this :

1. dangerouslySetInnerHTML
2. Storing content in form array object [html content] ( pushing a String content to array won't work ).
3. Passing unicode characters for all html entities.

This Question discuss these approaches pretty well :

[Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

My Queries are :

1. **Should there be change in over all flow/architecture to handle this?**
2. **What is best way to insert large html content from ajax call to react component to render ?**
3. **What design decisions should be considered to make fully functional and dynamic/scalable Blog ?**
4. **How to get SEO on your dynamic content like blog content ( which is stored in some file/database ). ?**

Comment: first thing you should never store html directly into data base...you should convert it into html entities (for security reasons you should not even accept any html from user input)!!! If you are talking about a json file there is no best way... I would go with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (just my personal opinion)

Comment: @Nishanth Matha How does sites like stackoverflow (let us add html content ) stores it ? Is there any defined way ? Here i am not considering user input . Consider i have written blog and want to show it on UI.

Comment: @AnilSharma Pretty sure stackoverflow html encodes the contents before adding it to a database. Then it decodes it back when displaying.

Comment: One Way i know is add different characters like [bold] this text is bold[bold]. Then render my own markup on runtime first. I am hoping if there is any other way.

Comment: For something like a blog, i'd rather go with server side rendering rather than client. This would make handling SEO stuf a lot easier.

Comment: @jzm Server side rendering adds unwanted complexity. i think not every blog is using that. I think SEO will be last thing to worry for me. I want to be clear on Design first. How to store data ? How data should be flown to client ? Atlast how final design can be achieved using React ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Rendering HTML from javascript could always be dangerous, regardless of using React or not, depending on the source of said HTML. For example, if you are rendering a post that you created yourself, and saved to a database, then there is no danger (unless your database has been compromised). But let's say you have comments on a post, and an user sends malicious code as a comment. All other users accessing that page, would fetch the malicious code from the database, and "dangerously" execute it on their browsers. So, what you need to do, is  make sure the source of HTML is secure, by sanitizing any user input BEFORE saving to the database. There are libraries you can use to achieve that, example - http://htmlpurifier.org/

Regarding SEO, you can use server side rendering - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/server-side-rendering-react-node-express/

Make sure you have all the information you need available on the url, so you don't rely on "state" to render a page, like post id, etc. You can achieve that by using React Router - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Comment: @HugoThanks for your reply. Its exactly what i am doing right now. While doing this i wanted to know how other blogs work and what are good practices to handle content oriented sites. Currently i am using react router for client side rendering and fetching blog content data from json api to dynamically load into React component and then before setting using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I might use serverside rendering in future. (Though i am not big fan for that ).

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not working for html tags. it is not even working on homepage of React[link](https://facebook.github.io/react/). Type <h1>this is heading.</h1>