# ReactJS - JSON and HTML markup

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I am looping through JSON and need to include some links.

My JSON looks like this:

```
"text": ["Nähere Informationen zu den Funktionalitäten der Plattform und der Dienste finden Sie unter <a href=\"/features\">/features</a>."],
```

But when I loop through and expose the data, it just exposes plain text HTML.

```
<div className='small-53 medium-54 large-55 medium-offset-1 large-offset-1 columns end'>
    <p className='text--uppercase text--book border--solid--bottom-red padding-bottom-10'>
        {item.title}
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div className='small-53 medium-54 large-55 medium-offset-1 large-offset-1 columns end'>
  <p className='text--uppercase text--book border--solid--bottom-red padding-bottom-10' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: item.title} }/>
</div>
```

You can read more about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)