# React: how do I render source code in a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I store some html source code in database, it's a block of code like this:

```
<div class="content"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>
```

Now in react I get them in a variable (`{this.state.content}`), but when I try to render them the source code got displayed as a string. Here's how I use it:

```
<div>
    {this.state.content}
</div>
```

On page it just shows the source code directly. How do I get them render as html source code instead of a string?

Comment: Are you talking about rendering html tags on the screen and not have it become a DOM element? If so, you need to escape them. https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp

Comment: React provides an attribute for doing this, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.  however, from the name, it should be obvious that this isn't a recommended practice, and you should consider more managed alternatives.  In general, storing HTML in variables or in your database is a common attack vector.

Comment: @Andrew It's actually the opposite way. I want it to become a DOM element instead of displaying the html tags on screen.

Comment: @Claies That worked. Thank you. Also good suggestion, I'll also keep this as bad practice in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are trying to set raw HTML. Try this.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}}></div>
```

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)