# React props: Using an HTML entity within JSX dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a [React component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component), to whose props I want to assign a string that includes both JavaScript variables and HTML entities.

Some of the approaches I've attempted have resulted in the HTML entity being rendered escaped. For example, `&ndash;` gets rendered literally as "`&ndash;`" instead of as "`–`".

Is there a way to get an HTML entity to render unescaped in a JSX dynamic content block being assigned to a React props?

### Attempts Made

Tried using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<MyPanel title={`${name} &ndash; ${description}`}> ... </MyPanel>
```

Problem: In the rendered output, the `&ndash;` is being rendered literally as "`&ndash;`" instead of as "`–`".

---

Attempted to construct some simple JSX with no quotes:

```
<MyPanel title={{name} &ndash; {description}} ... </MyPanel>
```

Problem: This failed at compile time with a syntax error.

---

Tried working around the syntax error by wrapping the JSX in a `<span />` element:

```
<MyPanel title={<span>{name} &ndash; {description}</span>} ... </MyPanel>
```

Problem: This works, but I'd rather avoid the superfluous `<span />` element being present in the rendered output.

---

Tried replacing the HTML entity with a Unicode numeric character reference:

```
<MyPanel title={name + ' \u2013 ' + description} ... </MyPanel>
```

Problems:

- This works, but (in my opinion) makes the code a little less
  readable. (It's more obvious that "ndash" rather than "2013"
  represents an en-dash character.)
- Also, this involves `+`-operator concatenation, which triggers a `Unexpected string concatenation  prefer-template` error in my team's JSLint checker; a solution that uses string interpolation instead would be better.

Comment: would `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on the  child elements of `<MyPanel />` work?

Comment: Assign it to a variable, then use it: `let temp_str = `${name} &ndash; ${description}``

Comment: @Tony: It's being used in a `title` attribute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I saw the `title` prop but (perhaps incorrectly?) assumed `<MyPanel />` would be rendering some actual element be it a h1, div, p etc.

Comment: It would help people help you if you updated your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @Tony: You may be right, given the thing about a `span` having worked. Allowing HTML in a prop and then using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, though, would be...dangerous. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh most definitely!

Comment: I'm AGAINS React replacing `&ndash;` with `–` in string variables because such feature brings a need to preprocess the string when you want to show it as is (e.g. to show a user comment). Such replacement is suitable only for JSX (which is almost a HTML).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can avoid the superfluous `span` with a `Fragment`:

```
<MyPanel title={<>{name} &ndash; {description}</>} ... </MyPanel>
```

This feature was introduced in React 16.2.

See the [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

---

I agree with [@samanime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813723/2479481) that using the actual character is best for simple cases, but if your content is truly dynamic, I would prefer using a `Fragment` over either the [`entityToChar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813723/2479481) or [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813732/2479481) approaches.

Answer (score 17):

Here are a few options (I outlined these in a more [general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958683/438581) awhile back):

1. Easiest - Use Unicode

   ```
   <MyPanel title={ `${name} – ${description}` } />
   ```
2. Safer - Use the Unicode number for the entity inside a Javascript string.

   ```
   <MyPanel title={`${name} \u2013 ${description}`} />
   ```

   or

   ```
   <MyPanel title={`${name} ${String.fromCharCode(8211)} ${description}`} />
   ```
3. Last Resort - Insert raw HTML using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

   ```
   title={`${name} &ndash; ${description}`}
   ```

   with:

   ```
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.title}}></div>
   ```

```js
const MyPanel = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.title}</div>
  )
}

const MyPanelwithDangerousHTML = (props) => {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.title}}></div>
  )
}

var description = "description";
var name = "name";

ReactDOM.render(<MyPanel title={`${name} – ${description}`} />
, document.getElementById("option1"));

ReactDOM.render(<MyPanel title={`${name} \u2013 ${description}`} />
, document.getElementById("option2"));

ReactDOM.render(<MyPanel title={`${name} ${String.fromCharCode(8211)} ${description}`} />
, document.getElementById("option3"));

ReactDOM.render(<MyPanelwithDangerousHTML title={`${name} &ndash; ${description}`} />
, document.getElementById("option4"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="option1"></div>
<div id="option2"></div>
<div id="option3"></div>
<div id="option4"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is React's documentation on HTML entities: [JSX Gotchas](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)

Of those, using the actual character instead of the HTML entity would be the best:

```
<MyPanel title={ `${name} – ${description}` } />
```

If you can't do that because the HTML entity is dynamic (it's not just a hard-coded en-dash), you could translate the entity. Here is a little function that can do that:

```
const entityToChar = str => { 
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea'); 
  textarea.innerHTML = str; 
  return textarea.value; 
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
<MyPanel title={ entityToChar(`${name} &ndash; ${description}`) } />
```

Comment: The problem being, of course, that just like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, that means the component happily renders HTML content it receives via props which, like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, is...dangerous. :-)

Comment: It is a bit better than `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` because it would then come back out as the `textarea` value, which would strip a lot of the HTML out.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how `<MyPanel />` works, I can only speculate that you could do something like the following:

```
<MyPanel title={`${name} &ndash; ${description}`}> ... </MyPanel>
```

MyPanel.js

```
render() {
    const { title } = this.props;

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably don't want to allow arbitrary URL in your `title` prop, I'd be tempted to write myself a function that **only** handles turning character entities into their Unicode character equivalent. Sort of "HTML-lite." :-) There aren't that many [named references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-character-references), really; and the numeric ones are easy:

```
const named = {
  "ndash": "–", // or "\u2013"
  "mdash": "—", // or "\u2014"
  "nbsp": " "   // or "\u00A0"
  // ...
};
// Obviously this is a SKETCH, not production code!
function convertCharEntities(str) {
  return str.replace(/&([^ ;&]+);/g, (_, ref) => {
    let ch;
    if (ref[0] === "#") {
      let num;
      if (ref[0].toLowerCase() === "x") {
        num = parseInt(ref.substring(2), 16);
      } else {
        num = parseInt(ref, 10);
      }
      ch = String.fromCodePoint(num);
    } else {
      ch = named[ref.toLowerCase()];
    }
    return ch || "";
  });
}
```

Then use it when rendering that prop:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{convertCharEntities(this.props.title || "")}</div>;
  }
}
```

Full Live Example:

```js
const named = {
  "ndash": "–", // or "\u2013"
  "mdash": "—", // or "\u2014"
  "nbsp": " "   // or "\u00A0"
  // ...
};
// Obviously this is a SKETCH, not production code!
function convertCharEntities(str) {
  return str.replace(/&([^ ;&]+);/g, (_, ref) => {
    let ch;
    if (ref[0] === "#") {
      let num;
      if (ref[0].toLowerCase() === "x") {
        num = parseInt(ref.substring(2), 16);
      } else {
        num = parseInt(ref, 10);
      }
      ch = String.fromCodePoint(num);
    } else {
      ch = named[ref.toLowerCase()];
    }
    return ch || "";
  });
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{convertCharEntities(this.props.title || "")}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Testing&nbsp;1&#160;2&#xa0;3&nbsp;&mdash; enh, you know the drill <script src='nefarious.js'><\/script>" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the *tags* were not output as tags, but the entities were handled.