# React: Raw HTML tag in content

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-dom

I am working on a React app.
There is some dynamic content which contents HTML tags. When I am showing that content on the page, it's showing with raw HTML tag.

For say:

```
const msg = "Some <strong>text</strong> here"
```

I want to show like this on page
Some **text** here

If I use `dangerousHtml` then it's showing like this without bold "Some text here"

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written.

Comment: there is no `dangerousHtml`.

Comment: Hi Luke it's just an example. I meant if I use dangerousHTML then HTML tags are not showing on the page but the bold effect is not coming also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' like:

```
const msg = () => ({__html: 'Some <strong>text</strong> here'});
```

and use it in your code like:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

For reference for 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' read this:

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: Or without a function: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "Some <strong>text</strong> here" }} />

Comment: Thanks for the reply hitesh and Daniel, I have used like you said but then its showing like this "Some text here". I need to bold the word "text" with <strong> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add raw-html-react
```

or

```
npm install raw-html-react

import ReactHtml from 'raw-html-react';

const html = `<div data-react-component="MyComponent"></div>`;
return <ReactHtml html={html} componentMap={{ MyComponent }} />;
```