# is there a way to convert static HTML to React components by using some libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

i am looking into ways to automate the manual process of converting the HTML templates into React components ,Please suggest any method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: what about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 4):

Reactjs.net provides an online utility to convert html to jsx. https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm

You can specify the name of the component as well.

Alternatively, you can look for a node module that does this conversion.
I haven't tried them personally. Here's one of them.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltojsx

Comment: Sorter-thanks for your response does this module helps me to create react components also or just converts to JSX