# How can I make some text from a json string bold?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, string

I want to concatenate two strings in react such that the first displays bold and the second does not. I have the string I want bolded in a JSON file and I have the string I want to concatenate coming from backend API call. Here's my setup:

This is in a JSON file:

```
  { stuff: {
    stuffIWantBolded: "bold text"
    }
  }
```

And my frontend looks like this:

```
  render() {
      // props for this component in which I'm rendering SomeComponent (see below)
      const { data } = this.props
      const { theStringFromBackend } = data
      // a method to get the string that is working for me
      const stuff = this.getTheStringFromTheJSON();
      const textIWantToDisplay = `${stuff.stuffIWantBolded} ${theStringFromBackend}`;
         return (
          <SomeComponent someProp={textIWantToDisplay} />
        );
     };
```

That concatenates the two strings successfully. I've tried using `.bold()` at the end of `stuff.stuffIWantBolded`, but that apparently doesn't work, because then the string renders as `<b>bold text</b> the string from backend` (assuming that's what the string from backend says), with the HTML tags written out explicitly instead of rendering actual bold text. Is there something I'm missing? I don't think one can just make the string bold in the JSON...perhaps I need to use a regex? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
return (
  <>
    <span style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{stuff.stuffIWantBolded}</span>
    <span>{theStringFromBackend}</span>
  </>
);
```

The `<>` and `</>` effectively allow you to return multiple items from one render function.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I just want to pass a prop to `<SomeComponent />` as in the component depicted in my question `<SomeComponent someProp={textIWantToDisplay} />`, and that prop is called `someProp`, can I still render bold and non-bold concatenated strings and pass that into `someProp`?

Comment: You can pass JSX or another component as a prop, yes. The syntax is a little tricky and may require some googling. But at some point you're going to need a span with css, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by using composition (I prefer the `strong` tag to `b` to make text bold):

```
render() {
  // props for this component in which I'm rendering SomeComponent (see below)
  const { data } = this.props
  const { theStringFromBackend } = data
  // a method to get the string that is working for me
  const stuff = this.getTheStringFromTheJSON();
     return (
      <SomeComponent>
        <p><strong>{stuff.stuffIWantBolded}</strong> {theStringFromBackend}</p>
      </SomeComponent>
    );
 };
```

And in `SomeComponent` you will find the nested html inside `props.children`

for more info check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks guys...these are all great answers. I suppose what still isn't clicking with me is that I want to keep `<SomeComponent />` a closed tag without adding any span elements inside of it. I want to only pass the `textIWantToDisplay` as a prop, which I've called `someProp`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you CAN pass in a prop within a self-closing tag component the way I want to. Not sure if it's conventionally sound/overly bloated but it looks like this:

```
     render() {
      // props for this component in which I'm rendering SomeComponent (see below)
      const { data } = this.props
      const { theStringFromBackend } = data
      // a method to get the string that is working for me
      const stuff = this.getTheStringFromTheJSON();
      const theBoldedText = `${stuff.stuffIWantBolded}`;
         return (
          <SomeComponent someProp={<span><b>{theBoldedText}</b> <span>{theStringFromBackend}</span></span>} />
        );
     };
```

Comment: Sure it works, but that's ugly as hell :)
Can I ask you why you so desperately need a self closing component?

Comment: I need it to be self-closing because it's a component that's been imported into a larger component and it has a ton of props associated with it. Moreover I didn't mention this in the question but it's a component that's wrapped inside a label composer and the prop `someProp` actually belongs to the label composer rather than `SomeComponent`. So `SomeComponent` needs a label associated with it rather than inside of it. I don't know if I'm making much sense since I'm a new coder but that's what it is.