# How to display HTML tags in React fetched from the database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

For eg:
In DB,

```
{
"text" : "<p>This is a text</p>"
}
```

But in front-end it displays :

```
<p>This is a text</p>
```

How to interpret as an HTML tag in react?

Comment: You can find safer way to add html [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

You can set HTML directly using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```js
function App() {
  const data = [
    { "text" : '<p>This is a text</p>' },
    { "text" : '<p style="color: red">Hello World</p>' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => <UnsafeComponent html={item.text} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

function UnsafeComponent({ html }) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,working fine as expected. but it is vulnerable to XSS (Cross site scripting).

Comment: Sure, as documentation states _setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack._ Using this technique you need to care take of data security yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to secure data by dangerouslySetInnerHTML using this?