# getElementsByTagName not working with InAppBrowser in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

Our website is loaded in the InAppBrowser of our Cordova app and I'm trying to get all the link tags by using executeScript like this:

```
  getAllLinks() {
    inappbrowser.executeScript({
        code: "(function(){ \
            return document.getElementsByTagName('a'); \
        })();"
    },function(values){
        console.log("length values = " + values.length); // length is always 1
        for(var x=0; x < values.length; x++) {
          var href = values[x].href;
          console.log("href = " + href);
        }
    });
  }

// loadstop_handler:
loadstop_handler(evt: InAppBrowserEvent) {
    if (device.platform == "Android") {
      this.getAllLinks();
    }
}

// loadstop handler is added to event listener:
inappbrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', (event) => this.loadstop_handler(event));
```

However I'm not getting the links. It returns an empty object and href is always undefined. There are about 10 links on the homepage when you open the app. I'm calling this method in the loadstop event. We are using Cordova 8.1.0 Can anyone help with this? How can I get the links?

**EDIT**

It seems according to this link:
https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/sharing-data-between-hybrid-app-and-inapp-browser/
you can't access the DOM of the website that's loaded in the InAppBrowser. It's a different context. That's why document.getElementByTagName returns undefined in executeScript.

So I applied the solution provided by the above link. This is not ideal, because I have to set data in the local storage from the website (as in: in the website code itself), like this:

```
// Code executed in website:
setLocalStorageForApp() {
    setTimeout(() => {  // waiting for DOM to load
      let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      var linkArray = new Array<string>();
      for (var x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
        var href = links.item(x).href;
        linkArray.push(href);
      }
      console.log('Total links = ' + linkArray.length); // result is 63
      localStorage.setItem('linkArray', JSON.stringify(linkArray));
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Then in the Cordova app I can fetch the a tags from the localstorage:

```
var links = null;
inappbrowser.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.getItem('linkArray')" }, function(values) {
  links = JSON.parse(values[0]);
  console.log(links); // prints all 63 links from web page
});
```

So from the app you can't access the context of the website loaded in InAppBrowser. The only way to share data (which apparently includes 'document') is by local storage.
If I have this wrong or someone knows a better solution which doesn't require me to modify the code of the website itself, please tell me. I have tried everything by now trying to get elements from the website's DOM, but everything failed.

Comment: If you can use fat arrows, you should be able to use `document.querySelectorAll('a')` but where is `return document.getElementsByTagName('a');` returned to in the IIFE? And is the IIFE run before there are any links rendered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

The return argument is always wrapped in a single element array. Try this:

```
getAllLinks() {
    inappbrowser.executeScript({
        code: "(function(){ \
            return document.getElementsByTagName('a'); \
        })();"
    },function(values){
        values = values[0]; // destructure single element array
        console.log("length values = " + values.length);
        for(var x=0; x < values.length; x++) {
          var href = values[x].href;
          console.log("href = " + href);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but also returned undefined.