# Is it possible to set a String as html element then use innerhtml on it in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {

        var formula = "<div> hello </div>"
        
        const div = document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML = formula

        return (

            <div>

                {div}

            </div>



        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I get an error

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLLIElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Basically the string has html elements I want to set inner html to the div constant. Right now yeah its relatively simple I just need to know if this can be done

My original code has something like this littered throughout my code in recursions too

```
var formula = "<div>"
formula = formula + "something"
formula = formula + "</div>
```

Comment: You might want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: react is used so that we don't need to manipulate the DOM directly using the getElementById etc like native JS. react has virtual DOM in memory and it will re-render when there is a change in state. If you surely want to manipulate DOM and know what you are doing, use a ref using useRef() hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done this way in React. A component can only return a ReactElement or JSXElement. If for some reason you absolutely need to set HTML from a string (there are reasons for this), you have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) which was made for that precise purpose, but exposes potential security vulnerabilities as explained in the documentation.

You can accomplish this as detailed in the official example:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
 
    createMarkup() {
       return {__html: 'Hello'};
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()}/>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

But again, this is discouraged and I'm curious to know why you can't just return JSX markup as the other answers suggest.

Comment: This worked! My original code is constantly adding elements to formula so idk how to do that in jsx

Comment: E.g.

```var formula = "<div>"
 formula = formula + "something"
formula = formula + "</div>"```

I'd love to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the same as above
`

Comment: Please post your full code. There are certainly much simpler ways to do this with React. But before going further I would give a thorough read through of their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a element you can directly use :

```
   class App extends React.Component {
       render() {

           const formula =<div> hello </div>
           
          
           return (

               <div>

                   {formula}

               </div>



           );
       }
   }

   export default App;
```

Comment: Not element, it is a JSX.

Comment: In my original code this wont work because formula isn't a const its a variable that I constantly add stuff too along the way i.e. `formula = formula + "<div> hello </div>"

Comment: Do you mean formula is a string ?

Comment: yeah it must be a string im too far gone in this

Comment: you can directly render the string in render block right ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating div like that? I’m begginer in ReactJs ,but I think you shouldn’t touch / create HTML DOM Elements like that at all or if it is not neccesary.

You can simply just do this .

```
Let formula = <div> hello </div>

Return(
  <div>
    {formula}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with useState.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {

  const [formula, setFormula] = useState("");

  setFormula(<div> 'hello' </div>);


  return(
    <div>
      {formula}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```