# Parse <br> tags that are a part of a string HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex

I have a text input. I want the line breaks that the user creates to be included in the output text.

When the user clicks preview, the input value is stored in state as a string. I use .replace() to replace the line breaks with br, but the tags are visible in the output html.

```
DesPreviewRender = () => {
    const desStateCopyOutput = this.state.inputValues.desValue.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' <br> ');
    return (
        <FadeIn>
            <div className="desPreview--Temp">
                <p className="desPreviewValueText--Temp">
                    {desStateCopyOutput}
                </p>
            </div>
        </FadeIn>
    )
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[Screenshot of html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vJpA.png)

Thanks!

Comment: aren't you looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56394170/3390200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SuperDJ said, I can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (maybe not the best way, but it works):

```
  generateOutput = input => {
    const lines = input.split('\n')  
    const output = []
    lines.forEach((d, i) => {
      if (i > 0) {
        output.push(<br/>)
      }
      output.push(d)
    })
    return output
  }
```