# Uncaught error when trying to render [object HTMLDocument] inside <iframe> in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Initially, inside a React application, I retrieved HTML file from server as a string and passed it to the iframe's srcDoc to display HTML inside a webpage which is fine. But now, I've been trying to parse that string (using new DOMParser()), store it in a variable and add it as a child of , but this error pops up "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDocument])". Could you please explain the concept behind rendering raw HTML code inside JSX or the workaround for this problem?

```
setFile(new DOMParser().parseFromString(res.data, 'text/html'))
...
...
return render ? (
    <iframe width='800' height='800'>
      {file}
    </iframe>
): null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: If you are referring to dangerouslySetInnerHTML property, I think I'm still passing the string to it and not the converted object. I would be okay with using the srcDoc, but when I go to inspect element, it displays the whole html code as a string which I don't want.

Comment: Why do you need to use `DOMParser`?

Comment: When I use srcDoc, the iframe element has a #document child which contains the html code I want, but as I mentioned it also displays the same code as a string in srcDoc. I figured if I extract the code as raw HTML using DOMParser, and then pass it down to iframe I don't have to deal with srcDoc. But apparently, it throws me an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't just pass children to `iframe` to render them anyway. You probably have to modify the dom directly here.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction as to how I do it?