# How to display html tag in string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a data

```
const Data = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Blablab<b>labl</b>abla',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: '2Blablab<b>labl</b>abla',
    },
  ];
```

`<p>{Data.title}</p>`

```
Output : Blablab<b>labl</b>abla 

tag <b></b> not render
```

the output i want is bold

The code above is just an example, for the data in my project I use the API and in the API the data type is string. inside the string contains the html tag but the html is not readable in the display

Comment: Are you using plain JS or some kind of framework or a template engine?

Comment: If you are using react check this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/how-to-render-html-string-as-real-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Using [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) ...

A sample e.g.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '2Blablab<b>labl</b>abla'}} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use markdown instead of dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
https://github.com/markedjs/marked