# To render a html table from a string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have written a function to generate a html table in a string:

```
board = "<table className='Board'><tbody><tr key="0"><Cell key="0-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="0-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="0-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="0-3" isLit={true} /></tr><tr key="1"><Cell key="1-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="1-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="1-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="1-3" isLit={true} /></tr><tr key="2"><Cell key="2-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="2-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="2-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="2-3" isLit={true} /></tr><tr key="3"><Cell key="3-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="3-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="3-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="3-3" isLit={true} /></tr><tr key="4"><Cell key="4-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="4-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="4-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="4-3" isLit={true} /></tr><tr key="5"><Cell key="5-0" isLit={true} /><Cell key="5-1" isLit={true} /><Cell key="5-2" isLit={true} /><Cell key="5-3" isLit={true} /></tr></tbody></table>"
```

If I format it in VSCode, I will a proper table:

```
<table className='Board'>
    <tbody>
        <tr key="0">
            <Cell key="0-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="0-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="0-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="0-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
        <tr key="1">
            <Cell key="1-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="1-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="1-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="1-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
        <tr key="2">
            <Cell key="2-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="2-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="2-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="2-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
        <tr key="3">
            <Cell key="3-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="3-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="3-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="3-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
        <tr key="4">
            <Cell key="4-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="4-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="4-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="4-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
        <tr key="5">
            <Cell key="5-0" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="5-1" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="5-2" isLit={true} />
            <Cell key="5-3" isLit={true} />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And if I cut and paste directly into an react component in the render, it will show a table.

However, if I were to display the string using a variable,

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {board}
      </div >
    )
  }
```

I won't get the table. It just show a string.

[image]

I've tried adding "\n" and < br > but it does not show a table.

How do I display the table from this string ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like following:

**Method1**

```js
npm i html-react-parser

import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
<div>{Parser(board)}</div>
```

**Method2:**

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: board }} />
```

Comment: it didn't form the table, It formed this: <div class="App"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell>

Comment: <cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"><cell islit="{true}"></cell></cell></cell></cell><table class="Board"><tbody><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table></div>

Comment: Seems like the parsing is not working ?

Comment: @EBDS i have updated my answer. if it still not working then can you please provice me codesandbox ? so that we both are on same page.

Comment: @EBDS what is <Cell> tag? are you using UI components?

Comment: @EBDS I tried replacing <cell /> with <td /> and its working at my side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252342/discussion-between-ram-chander-and-ebds).