# How to convert received JSON data to HTML tags in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to convert received JSON data to HTML tags in React?

my code:

```
{JSON.stringify(setData.Element_008.value?.Element_001)}

# in Element_008
{
    "type": "ItemPartBox",
    "value": {
        "Element_000": "<FONT COLOR='#A9D0F5'>세트 효과 레벨</FONT>",
        "Element_001": "사멸 <FONT COLOR='#FFD200'>Lv.3</FONT>"
    }
}
```

I want to apply the font tag in text

I tried JSON data to stringify data. but I want font tag...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: Note that the `font` tag was deprecated in HTML 4...

Answer (score 1):

Use the **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** prop to insert the HTML from your JSON data into a React element.

```
const renderedHTMLElements = useMemo(() => {
    const htmlElements = [];
    const data = setData.Element_008.value;

    for (const key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const html = { __html: data[key] };
        htmlElements.push(
          <div key={key} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html}></div>
        );
      }
    }

    return htmlElements;
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {renderedHTMLElements}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop to inject HTML text into an element, but be sure to sanitize your input before assigning the `__html` value.

For demonstration purposes, I chose the [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/jitbit/HtmlSanitizer) library. It works out-of-the-box in the browser.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const sanitize  = (input) => HtmlSanitizer.SanitizeHtml(input);
const fetchData = ()      => Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA);

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        /* Conditinally render the <ul> */
        data.Element_008 != null && (
          <ul>
            {Object.entries(data.Element_008.value).map(([key, value]) => (
              <li
                key={key}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(value) }}
              ></li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const MOCK_DATA = {
  Element_008: {
    type: "ItemPartBox",
    value: {
      Element_000: "<FONT COLOR='#A9D0F5'>세트 효과 레벨</FONT>",
      Element_001: "사멸 <FONT COLOR='#FFD200'>Lv.3</FONT>",
    },
  },
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jitbit/HtmlSanitizer@master/HtmlSanitizer.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```