# innerHTML is showing incorrectly in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with local storage and trying to show its content in HTML. I use useState for showing it, value that I pass in it is innerHTML value, but it is now showing like what I'd expected - I expected like typical divs. Instead, it is showing like string divs.

in component Bar (function Bar() )

```
const [savedToDos, setSavedToDos] = React.useState(allStorage)

function allStorage() {
        let archive = []
        let keys = Object.keys(localStorage)

        let key;
        for (let i = 0 ; key = keys[i]; i++) {
            archive.push(`<div id="${key}">${localStorage.getItem(key)}</div>`);
        }

        let stringWithToDos = archive.join("")
        let divWithSavedToDos = document.createElement("div")
        
        divWithSavedToDos.innerHTML = stringWithToDos 

       return divWithSavedToDos.innerHTML
   
      
    }
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{  
        setSavedToDos(allStorage)

    }, [localStorage.length])


  return (
    <div className='bar'>
        <input
        ref={inputRef}
        id="barInput"
        type="text"
        placeholder="new to-do"
        onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={addNewToDo}>add</button>
        <div>{savedToDos}</div>
    </div>
  )
```

I expected that it will show smth like
item1
item2

But instead I get

`<div id="1">item1</div> <div id="2">item2</div>`

Thanks for help!

Comment: React has its own way of reconciling changes to the DOM. You shouldn't be using DOM methods like `createElement` or `innerHTML`. You might want to look at the [introductory documentation for React](https://react.dev/learn) to understand how it's used. As far as your example goes it's quite difficult to tell what it is you're doing, and which parts are component, and which parts are `allStorage` because you don't _call_ `allStorage` at all.

Comment: this is only partial code, I tried to show only necessary things. Everything that i showed is in Bar component. It is then in App component. But as I understood, it is about not using innerHTML in react, isnt it?

Comment: @Andy - it is called, by React, since the OP is using it as the argument to `setSavedToDos`, which means it is called as a "state updater function". (Which itself is super weird, since it doesn't depend at all on the previous state, and has side effects like adding a new div to the DOM!)

Comment: obviously I agree with Andy that you should absolutely not be ussing these direct DOM manipulation methods in React - but to answer your direct creation, you're getting that ouitput because that's what `innerHTML` gives you, all the HTML content *as a string of HTML code*. You probably wanted `innerText` instead for just the text content (but as was alreayd said, please don't actually do either of these when using React).

Comment: Thanks to you all, I will not use these DOM manipulations anymore.

Comment: @RobinZigmond fair point on the "state updater function", but it's a weird thing to do and I definitely wouldn't encourage it.

Comment: I totally agree with you, as I tried to make clear in my next comment - I just felt I had to correct you on `allStorage` never being called

Comment: [Not advised] There is way to render raw html in React. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs

Comment: Just one last thing; your method of saving and retrieving data from localstorage doesn't seem to be very efficient. It maybe better to store a single object and parse and iterate over that rather than fetch single items from localstorage in a loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not good to change DOM in React. React has it's own virtual DOM. You can use map function to render an element for each of an array element, which is the most standard and common way. To create a div element for each todo , it can be something like this:

```
<div class="column">
    {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div class="item">
            {todo}
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Get your todo array from local storage or anywhere else, and render it like this.