# How to pass HTML tags in props

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to pass text with HTML tags, like so:

```
<MyComponent text="This is <strong>not</strong> working." />
```

But inside of `MyComponent`'s render method, when I print out `this.props.text`, it literally prints out everything:

```
This is <strong>not</strong> working.
```

Is there some way to make React parse HTML and dump it out properly?

Comment: What is your actual render function?

Comment: The typical pattern would be to make your content children of your component `<MyComponent>This is <strong>not</strong> working</MyComponent>`, instead of passing them as props. Could you give more context on what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Almost the same question: [Reactjs convert to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html).

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can use mixed arrays with strings and JSX elements (see the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities)):

```
<MyComponent text={["This is ", <strong>not</strong>,  "working."]} />
```

There's a fiddle here that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/7s7dee6L/

Also, as a last resort, you always have [the ability to insert raw HTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) but be careful because that can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack if aren't sanitizing the property values.

Comment: This works, except I now get a warning: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of CTA. It was passed a child from Template1. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

Comment: You can make this error go away by going through the array and adding the index as a key in MyComponent

`{text.map( textOrHTML, index) =>
    <span key={index}>{textOrHTML}</span>
)}
`
Although, it's just so strange that we have to do this in the first place entirely.

Comment: You can also fix the warning by putting `key="[some unique value]"` on the `<strong>` element.

Comment: Nice, working fine, I would like to know how could I use a variable inside strong instead of string 'not'

Comment: In order to remove array key warning, it is also possible now to pass a single JSX like this.
`<MyComponent text={<>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</>} />`

Comment: for those wondering what the empty brackets are in @Arif answer, they are shorthand for a Fragment. I just started messing with react and learned that today

Answer (score 176):

Actually, there are multiple ways to go with that.

### You want to use JSX inside your props

You can simply use {} to cause JSX to parse the parameter. The only limitation is the same as for every JSX element: It must return only one root element.

```
myProp={<div><SomeComponent>Some String</div>}
```

The best readable way to go for this is to create a function renderMyProp that will return JSX components (just like the standard render function) and then simply call myProp={ this.renderMyProp() }

### You want to pass only HTML as a string

By default, JSX doesn't let you render raw HTML from string values. However, there is a way to make it do that:

```
myProp="<div>This is some html</div>"
```

Then in your component you can use it like that:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML=myProp={{ __html: this.renderMyProp() }}></div>
```

Beware that this solution 'can' open on cross-site scripting forgeries attacks. Also beware that you can only render simple HTML, no JSX tag or component or other fancy things.

### The array way

In react, you can pass an array of JSX elements.
That means:

```
myProp={["This is html", <span>Some other</span>, "and again some other"]}
```

I wouldn't recommend this method because:

- It will create a warning (missing keys)
- It's not readable
- It's not really the JSX way, it's more a hack than an intended design.

### The children way

Adding it for the sake of completeness but in react, you can also get all children that are 'inside' your component.

So if I take the following code:

```
<SomeComponent>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
</SomeComponent>
```

Then the two divs will be available as this.props.children in SomeComponent and can be rendered with the standard {} syntax.

This solution is perfect when you have only one HTML content to pass to your Component (Imagine a Popin component that only takes the content of the Popin as children).

However, if you have multiple contents, you can't use children (or you need at least to combine it with another solution here)

Comment: _this.props.childrens_ - but `this.props.children`. Without 's' https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren

Comment: This is a far better answer and should be the one selected as such.

Comment: If you do not want to add more HTML wrap in <> .... </>

Answer (score 37):

From React v16.02 you can use a Fragment.

```
<MyComponent text={<Fragment>This is an <strong>HTML</strong> string.</Fragment>} />
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Comment: This is the most useful answer if you are reading it in 2020

Comment: This only works for HTML you're defining inline, right? You can't do `<>{myHtml}</>` or something like that?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `<></>` Fragments to pass the HTML in the props.

```
<MyComponent text={<>"This is <strong>not</strong> working."</>} />
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#jsx-fragment-syntax

Comment: fits perfect for me. Don't need double quotes, as long as you don't want to render them on the screen: <MyComponent text={<>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</>} />

Answer (score 19):

You can use *dangerouslySetInnerHTML*

Just send the html as a normal string

```
<MyComponent text="This is <strong>not</strong> working." />
```

And render in in the JSX code like this:

```
<h2 className="header-title-right wow fadeInRight"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.text}} />
```

Just be careful if you are rendering data entered by the user. You can be victim of a XSS attack

Here's the documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: works nicely as I have to use a variable to put HTML content.

Answer (score 9):

On a client-side react application, there are a couple of ways of rendering a prop as a string with some html. One safer than the other...

## 1 - Define the prop as jsx (my preference)

```
const someProps = {
  greeting: {<div>Hello<a href="/${name_profile}">${name_profile}</a></div>}
}


const GreetingComopnent = props => (
  <p>{props.someProps.greeting}</p>
)
```

• The only requirement here is that whatever file is generating this prop needs to include React as a dependency (in case you're generating the prop's jsx in a helper file etc).

## 2 - Dangerously set the innerHtml

```
const someProps = {
  greeting: '<React.Fragment>Hello<a href="/${name_profile}">${name_profile}</a></React.Fragment>'
}

const GreetingComponent = props => {
  const innerHtml = { __html: props.someProps.greeting }
  return <p dangerouslySetInnerHtml={innerHtml}></p>
}
```

• This second approach is discouraged. Imagine an input field whose input value is rendered as a prop in this component. A user could enter a script tag in the input and the component that renders this input would execute this potentially malicious code. As such, this approach has the potential to introduce cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.
For more information, [refer to the official React docs](https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/taylor-swift-album.png?w=1000&h=562&crop=1)

Answer (score 8):

```
<MyComponent text={<span>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</span>} />
```

and then in your component you can do prop checking like so:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      text: React.PropTypes.object, // if you always want react components
      text: React.PropTypes.any, // if you want both text or react components
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you choose only one prop type.

Answer (score 8):

For me It worked by passing html tag in props children

```
<MyComponent>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</MyComponent>


var MyComponent = React.createClass({

   render: function() {
    return (
      <div>this.props.children</div>
    );
   },
```

Answer (score 7):

Set the text prop type to **any** and do this:

```
<MyComponent text={
    <React.Fragment>
        <div> Hello, World!</div>
    </React.Fragment>
    } 
/>
```

[Example](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#CustomizedTooltips.js)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in 2 ways that I am aware of.

1-  `<MyComponent text={<p>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</p>} />`

And then do this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render () {
     return (<div>{this.props.text}</div>)
   }
}
```

Or second approach do it like this

2- `<MyComponent><p>This is <strong>not</strong> working.</p><MyComponent/>`

And then do this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render () {
     return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>)
   }
}
```

Comment: I added a variable `let vhtml = "<p>Test</p>"` and used it on the prop like this `text={vhtml}` and it still rendered in plain text for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Parser from [html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) is a good solution. You just have to

- install it with npm or yarn
- import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
- call it with :

  ```
  <MyComponent text=Parser("This is <strong>not</strong> working.") />
  ```

  and it works well.

Answer (score 4):

You can successfully utilize [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for this task. Depending on the React version you use, you can use short syntax: `<>` or the full tag: `<React.Fragment>`. Works especially well if you don't want to wrap entire string within HTML tags.

```
<MyComponent text={<>Hello World. <u>Don't be so ruthless</u>.</>} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Do like this:

```
const MyText = () => {
     return (
          <>
               This is <strong>Now</strong> working.
          </>
     )
}
```

then pass it as a props as:

```
<MyComponent Text={MyText} />
```

now you can use it in your component:

```
const MyComponent = ({Text}) => {
     return (
          <>
               // your code
               {<Text />}
               // some more code
          </>
     )
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

@matagus answer is fine for me, Hope below snippet is helped those who wish to use a variable inside.

```
const myVar = 'not';
<MyComponent text={["This is ", <strong>{`${myVar}`}</strong>,  "working."]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a function on the component to pass along jsx to through props. like:

```
 var MyComponent = React.createClass({

   render: function() {
    return (
      <OtherComponent
        body={this.body}
      />
    );
   },

   body() {
     return(
       <p>This is <strong>now</strong> working.<p>
     );
   }

});

var OtherComponent = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    body: React.PropTypes.func
  },

  render: function() {
     return (
        <section>
          {this.props.body()}
        </section>
     );
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project I had to pass dynamic html snippet from variable and render it inside component. So i did the following.

```
defaultSelection : {
    innerHtml: {__html: '<strong>some text</strong>'}
}
```

**defaultSelection** object is passed to component from `.js` file

```
<HtmlSnippet innerHtml={defaultSelection.innerHtml} />
```

**HtmlSnippet** component

```
var HtmlSnippet = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.props.innerHtml}></span>
    );
  }
});
```

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kWibAt?p=preview)

[react doc for dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can it by using mix array with strings and JSX elements.  [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-entities)

```
<MyComponent text={["This is ", <strong>not</strong>,  "working."]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer: If you intend to parse and you are already in JSX but have an object with nested properties, a very elegant way is to use parentheses in order to force JSX parsing:

```
const TestPage = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <MyComponent property={
    {
      html: (
        <p>This is a <a href='#'>test</a> text!</p>
      )
    }}>
    </MyComponent>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already a lot of answers, but I had was doing something wrong related to this and I think is worth sharing:

I had something like this:

```js
export default function Features() {
  return (
    <Section message={<p>This is <strong>working</strong>.</p>} />
  }
}
```

but the massage was longer than that, so I tried using something like this:

```js
const message = () => <p>This longer message is <strong>not</strong> working.</p>;

export default function Features() {
  return (
    <Section message={message} />
  }
}
```

It took me a while to realize that I was missing the () in the function call.

**Not working**

```js
<Section message={message} />
```

**Working**

```js
<Section message={message()} />
```

maybe this helps you, as it did to me!

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same thing in such a way.

```
const Child = () => {
  return (
     write your whole HTML here.
  )
}
```

now you want to send this HTML inside another component which name is Parent component.

**Calling :-**

```
<Parent child={<child/>} >
</Parent>
```

**Use Of Child:-**

```
 const Parent = (props) => {
   const { child } = props; 
   return (
       {child}
    )
}
```

this work perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which is dangerous as the name says.

```
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

<FormattedMessage
          id="app.greeting"
          description="Bold text example"
          defaultMessage="Look here, I can include HTML tags in plain string and render them as HTML: <b>Bold</b>, <i>Italics</i> and <a>links too</a>."
          values={{
            b: (chunks) => <b>{chunks}</b>,
            i: (chunks) => <i>{chunks}</i>,
            a: (chunks) => (
              <a class="external_link" target="_blank" href="https://jiga.dev/">
                {chunks}
              </a>
            )
          }}
        />
```

This should be rendered as:

[image: react jiga.dev]

Full example in https://jiga.dev/react-render-string-with-html-tags-from-props/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<MyComponent text={<>some text <strong>bold text</strong> and more.</>} />
```

Also if you want to pass variable here, you can try like this

```
<MyComponent text={<>My name is {variableName}. <strong>Bold text</strong> normal text</>} />
```

Answer (score -9):

Have appended the html in componentDidMount using jQuery append. This should solve the problem.

```
 var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        return (
           <div>

           </div>
        );
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).append(this.props.text);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is down voted because you shouldn't be using jquery's direct DOM manipulation combined with react's indirect DOM manipulation, as it can lead to browser thrashing.