# Execute props value as HTML in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, react-props

I have below code in Child component.

```
<label>{this.props.label}</label>
```

My Parent component code is like below.

```
          <InputText label='<span className="text-danger">*</span> Email'/>
```

But the HTML is not executing. I am getting output like below

[image]

Comment: Try [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @Dupocas right answer, but bad idea

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/react-how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as he knows what he is doing. By exposing the content passed to `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to user input (or by not sanitizing it) `XSS` is really a problem. But this is not necessarily always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @Abdelhedihlel. Your solution is working. Thanks.