# Passing template literal as prop is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-strings

I've got a functional component

```
const Paragraph = forwardRef((ref: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.text }}></p>
    </div>
  );
});
```

When I call this component I can't render this template literal:

```
<Paragraph text={`${<a href="#">Terms of Service</a>} and ${<a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>}`} />
```

the result is:
`[object Object] and [object Object]`

Comment: You are passing JSX objects to the string template. Just remove the `${}` around your tags.

Comment: Can you post that as a comment? I want to accept yours as an answer

Comment: [Don't pass HTML at all, use JSX all the way.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33381029/1218980)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ES6 template literals takes expressions inside `${}` that it converts to strings. You are giving it JSX objects `${<a href="#">Terms of Service</a>}` which can't really be converted to a string representation, the best it can do is `[object Object]`.

What you really want is to set the inner HTML the the actual string `<a href="#">Terms of Service</a>`, so simply removing the `${}` around your tags will give you the expected result.

```
<Paragraph text={`<a href="#">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>`} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the ${} in your template string

Edit: I've just noticed that @super already mentioned that in the comment. 
Credits to him ;)