# Rect - pass HTML tags in props string - missing "key" value

Tags: reactjs

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/react-how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props), I am using this method to pass an short HTML code to the props, as a string:

```
<MyComponent text={["This is ", <strong>not</strong>,  "working."]} />
```

It works fine... almost fine.

React gives this warning:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MyComponent`. It was passed a child from TheParent. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at strong
```

Any way to pass the html this way, and put somehow key?
I'd like to avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you might need to edit your question, and add the code for MyComponent.

Comment: *short HTML code to the props, as a string* - not sure what this means, but probably not. You're passing **an array** as a prop. That **array** contains 3 elements - a string, a **JSX** element, and another string. When rendering elements from an array, (dynamically or not) you must provide a `key` to the element. See docs on the subject [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: in the loop give the parent element key and unique value like key={$i}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Also, the second answer to the question you linked is much better. I would recommend reading that one and using it instead.

Comment: Thank you @BrianThompson it looks like the best way is to set `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as the array way is not a good idea

Comment: I found another solution. It looks like that wrapping the html string in `<Fragment></Fragment>` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After React 16 you can use `<Fragment>`.

Just send the prop this way and it will work fine:

```
<MyComponent text={<Fragment>"This is <strong>not</strong> working."</Fragment>]} />
```