# How to add margin to label using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like below:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const name ="name1";
    const type = "type1";

    const label = `${name} ${type}`; //something to be done here to add some space 
    // before the text
    return (
        <CheckBox
            label={label}
        />
    );
}
```

For the above checkbox component, I am passing label prop.

How can I add some margin say `4px` before the text that is evaluated for label?

So, label is `name1 type1`

I would like some margin added before `name1 type1`.

How can it be done?

EDIT:

Checkbox is a reusable component and i want margin to be added to label only for ParentComponent.

below is the Checkbox component

```
type CheckboxProps = {
    label?: string;
}


const Checkbox: React.FC<CheckboxProps> = ({
    label,
}) => {
    return (
        <StyledCheckbox hasLabel = {!!label}/>
        <Label >label</Label>
    )
}
```

Comment: _"some margin added"_ - what's stopping you adding the margin?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you import `Checkbox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over this in the checkbox component props itself, you can nest the component within an element and style accordingly.

```js
const style = {marginLeft: 4}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const name ="name1";
    const type = "type1";

    const label = `${name} ${type}`; //something to be done here to add some space 
    // before the text
    return (
        <div style={style}>
          <CheckBox
            label={label}
          />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on mixed arrays. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/react-how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props) or the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities) for more info about it. You wrap the second element in a `span` and you give it a margin.

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const name ="name1";
    const type = "type1";

    const label = `${name} ${type}`; //something to be done here to add some space 
    // before the text
    return (
        <CheckBox
            label={[`${name}`, <span style={{marginLeft: '4px'}}>{type}</span>]}
        />
    );
}
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o1jykneq/3/ to see how it works.