# Inject children into react component passed by props in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a component where I want to append some stuff to the parent component passed by props. Something like:

```
function MyComponent(props : IMyProps) {
return ( {<props.parent>}{myStuff}{</props.parent>}
}
```

So I can call my new component like this:

```
<MyComponent parent={<h1 />} />
```

And MyComponent will append children to the h1 element. Can this be done?

Comment: Please, check out these question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/react-how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props)

Answer (score 1):

`parent` is already is a JSX, but your problem is you haven't passed `children` which is representing `myStuff`

*Note that React's components are only callable with the first-letter-capitalized names, so I've assigned `parent` to `Parent`, and in the meanwhile, I've also added `React.Fragment` to prevent undefined-value cases from `parent`.*

```js
const MyComponent = ({ parent }) => {
   const Parent = parent || React.Fragment //convert it to a callable component
   const myStuff = "Testing" //simulating your stuff
   return <Parent>{myStuff}</Parent>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent parent={({children}) => <h1>{children}</h1>}/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you only want to pass `<h1/>`, you need to clone the element and pass `children` in `MyComponent` by [`React.cloneElement`](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-cloneelement-function/)

```js
const MyComponent = ({ parent }) => {
   const myStuff = "Testing" //simulating your stuff
   return React.cloneElement(parent, {}, myStuff)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent parent={<h1/>}/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```