# Pass a div in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a component:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={toggle}
        className=""
      >
        {props.label}
      </button>
      {open && <div className="toggle">{props.children}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then I call this component in my App.tsx:

```
<Component label="test">
<p>Hello</p>
</Component>
```

Basically it is a toggle, open/close the children. In this example the `test` is where you click to open/close. But I aim for something like this (so not to use a label but instead something custom):

```
<Component { <div className="bg-purple-200 text-5xl font-bold">Hello</div> } >
<p>Hello</p>
</Component>
```

Ofcourse the toggle button in my Component component would then also need to be changed accordingly.

Is that possible and allowed to do? I am trying to write it correctly.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props/46484325#46484325

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass HTML tags in props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381029/how-to-pass-html-tags-in-props)

Comment: @pilchard yes, thank you.