# How do I convert a string to jsx?

Tags: reactjs

How would I take a string, and convert it to `jsx`?  For example, if I bring in a string from a `textarea`, how could I convert it to a `React` element;

```
var jsxString = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
```

What is the process I would use to convert this on the client?  Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample string you'd like to convert to JSX?

Comment: `<div>Hello World</div>`

Comment: Your sample string is just pure HTML. If you just want to inject HTML then `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the way to go. I can flesh this out in a more detailed answer if you like.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh it is HTML but it is also valid JSX

Answer (score 59):

You can consider using the React attribute `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
class YourComponent{
  render() {
    someHtml = '<div><strong>blablabla<strong><p>another blbla</p/></div>'
     
    return (
      <div className="Container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: someHtml}}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working in case of rendering **React Components**
`Don't see your post <Link to=\"/add-professor\">Add Your Post</Link>`
In this case `<Link>` is not getting rendered as it should be

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` doesn't allow for camel-case name inside of tags and it will convert them to lower case. This is because it is meant for html tags.

Comment: **Warning** : `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is vulnurable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 36):

### 2023 answer update

Seem **react-html-parser** has no longer been maintained for a few years already. As pointed on the comment by [Bill Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271055/bill-keller), there is a library still actively maintained named **html-react-parser**. However, please read carefully on the Readme and make some considerations before using it in production. Like in this section [Is this XSS safe?](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser#is-this-xss-safe), if it is acceptable, then you are good to go.

Another alternative sounds more promising to me because it emphasizes "Safely" on their repo and home page. The library is named "Interweave". Please check the following repo for more detail about installation and usage: https://github.com/milesj/interweave/

### 2018 answer

Personally, I love to do it just like in the previous answer which recommends the usage of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property in JSX.

Just for an alternative, nowadays there is a library called **react-html-parser**. You can check it and install from NPM registry at this URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser. Today's weekly download statistic for that package is **23,696**. Looks a quite popular library to use. Even it looks more convenient to use, my self, still need more read and further consideration before really using it.

Code snippet copied from the NPM page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const html = '<div>Example HTML string</div>';
    return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Much better than the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` option in my opinion

Comment: It does the same thing as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. No use

Comment: The year is 2020. The active Github repo to check out is: [https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser)

Comment: @Trect, you better check the documentation. Though actually now it is outdated. Please check updated answer for more updated lib and better alternative.

Comment: @BillKeller, thanks for sharing. I have updated my answer based on your suggestion. You might be interested in checking it out. It has an additional library mentioned there. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Here's how you can do it, without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```js
import React from "react";

let getNodes = str =>
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.childNodes;
let createJSX = nodeArray => {
  return nodeArray.map(node => {
    let attributeObj = {};
    const {
      attributes,
      localName,
      childNodes,
      nodeValue
    } = node;
    if (attributes) {
      Array.from(attributes).forEach(attribute => {
        if (attribute.name === "style") {
          let styleAttributes = attribute.nodeValue.split(";");
          let styleObj = {};
          styleAttributes.forEach(attribute => {
            let [key, value] = attribute.split(":");
            styleObj[key] = value;
          });
          attributeObj[attribute.name] = styleObj;
        } else {
          attributeObj[attribute.name] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
      });
    }
    return localName ?
      React.createElement(
        localName,
        attributeObj,
        childNodes && Array.isArray(Array.from(childNodes)) ?
        createJSX(Array.from(childNodes)) :
        []
      ) :
      nodeValue;
  });
};

export const StringToJSX = props => {
  return createJSX(Array.from(getNodes(props.domString)));
};
```

Import `StringToJSX` and pass the string in as props in the following format.

```
<StringToJSX domString={domString}/>
```

PS: I might have missed out on a few edge cases like attributes.

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have the most upvotes.. Fantastic! I used this for svg's although I had to change a bunch, but still helped a whole bunch! dangerouslySetInnerHtml doesn't work that well with SVG's, this works great.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with server-side rendering because `DOMParser` is browser specific

Comment: @EtienneMartin Should be able to use jsdom the same way from Node

Comment: here is this function (with typescript) in a blitz if anyone wants to play around with it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kbt7rs?file=StringToJSX.tsx,App.tsx

Comment: Not good enough, it converts React components to lowercase

Answer (score 16):

I came across this answer recently and, it was a good deal for me. You don't need to provide a string. Returning an array of JSX elements will do the trick.

We can store JSX elements in JavaScript array.

```
let arrUsers = [<li>Steve</li>,<li>Bob</li>,<li>Michael</li>];
```

and in your HTML (JSX) bind it like,

```
<ul>{arrUsers}</ul>
```

As simple as it is.

Comment: this works if the content is dynamic, what if the tag name itslef is dynamic?

Comment: Great and easy solution! Worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

If you consider string

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

If we are very strict, this actually is the valid JSX. The question is how to compile this JSX string into React code.

Easiest and the recommended way is to download some library like Babel and use it to transform the code. Babel can run in the Browser like the [repl does](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-0&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=%3Cdiv%3EHello%20World%3C%2Fdiv%3E).

**It is also possible to transform JSX to other formats**, but in this case you have to find a compiler or create one yourself.

The steps to create the JSX => React transformation yourself is:

1. transform the code string into AST representation
2. parse the AST and output code back to string

So you need somekind of AST parser like [espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) supporting JSX and then you can create a code which walks the AST tree and outputs something, like React -code out of it.

The AST tree of JSX data consists of normal JavaScript AST together with JSX nodes. The parser should walk through the tree and transform the JSX nodes into normal JavaScript code.

If you compile to React and encounter a JSX node with tag "div" you should compile that into `React.createElement("div",...` call with attributes and subnodes found under that AST node inserted as parameters of that call.

I have created a small AST Walker, which can process AST tree, [ASTWalker](https://github.com/terotests/ASTWalker/), which can be used to transform the AST tree into some output format, like React or DOM.

On-line example of how to use it is here:

http://codepen.io/teroktolonen/pen/KzWVqx?editors=1010

The main code looks like this:

```
    // here is the JSX string to parse
    var codeStr = "<div>Hello world</div>";
    var walker = ASTWalker({
        defaultNamespace: "react",
    });
    // compile AST representation out of it.
    var rawAST = espree.parse(codeStr, {
          ecmaVersion: 6,
          sourceType: "script",
          // specify additional language features
          ecmaFeatures: {
            // enable JSX parsing
            jsx: true
          } 
        });

   // then you can walk the walk to create the code
   walker.startWalk( rawAST, {} );
   var code = walker.getCode();  
   console.log(code); 
   document.getElementById("sourceCode").innerHTML = code;
```

DISCLAIMER: The library is not intented for compiling into React. It is mostly used with `defaultNamespace: "DOM",` using it to compile into plain JavaScript + DOM representation. Trying anything more complicated than simple tags may result as an error.

The important thing is to notice that React is not only possible output format for JSX.

Comment: What you have here: `<div>Hello World</div>` isn't a string. But you are right to say that it is JSX. This: `"<div>Hello World</div>"` is a string and is not JSX. there is no such thing as a "JSX string". Be careful how you word your answers as it might be confusing.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using html-to-react with some success (self closing tags cause a problem though, but a fix is in the pull requests...) to parse markup strings as DOM like objects, and in turn React elements. It's not pretty, and if you can avoid it, do so. But it gets the job done.

html-to-react at github: https://github.com/mikenikles/html-to-react

Comment: The library is now at https://github.com/aknuds1/html-to-react This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

## Use `React-JSX-Parser`

You can use the React-JSX-Parser library dedicated for this.

`npm install react-jsx-parser`

[here](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser) is the repo

Answer (score 3):

[html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) is what you need.

```js
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import React from 'react';

export default function YourComponent() {
    someHtml = '<div><strong>blablabla<strong><p>another blbla</p/></div>'
     
    return (
        <div className="Container">{parse(someHtml)}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: html-react-parser is not able to detect function calls inside jsx

Comment: It converts React components to lowercase

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the library called [React Live](https://formidable.com/open-source/react-live/).

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little utility component for this:

```
const RawHtml = ({ children="", tag: Tag = 'div', ...props }) =>
  <Tag { ...props } dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: children }}/>;
```

Sample usage:

```
<RawHtml tag={'span'} style={{'font-weight':'bold'}}>
  {"Lorem<br/>ipsum"}
</RawHtml>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can change it to a `non-string` array and then use it as `JSX`

```
class ObjReplicate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { myText: '' };
  }
  
  textChange=(e) =>{this.setState({ myText: e.target.value })};

  render() {
    const toShow = this.state.myText;
    var i=1;
    var allObjs=new Array;
    while (i<100){
      i++;
      allObjs[i] = <p>{toShow}</p>; //non-sting array to use  in JSX
   }
   
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.textChange}></input>
        {allObjs}
      </div>
   );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ObjReplicate/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsxString = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
return <>{jsxString}</>;
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers allow you to maintain the capitalization of React components, in other words, just like with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, whenever the string is rendered, `ExampleComponent` becomes `examplecomponent` (in lower case).

Improving on [TheBotlyNoob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68583037/2334352), you can circumvent that by using [html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) and then replacing all *lowercased* React components. It's even more fluid as it allows you to define additional custom attributes on the replacement component, as well as preserve the component's children. For example:

```
import parse, { domToReact } from 'html-react-parser';
import SomeComponent from 'some-component';

...
const options = {
    replace: ({ attribs, children }) => {  
      if (!attribs) {
        return;
      }
      if (attribs.class === 'replace') {
        return <SomeComponent someAttribute="" className="anyClass">{domToReact(children, options)}</SomeComponent>
      }
    }
};

...
<div>
  {parse(dynamicHTML, options)}
</div>
```

Answer (score -9):

You need to use babel with preset [react](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react
```

Add the following line to your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Then run

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js
```

You can find more info [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli)

Comment: So there is no way to do it dynamically.  I have to run something from the command line to do it?  I want to be able to enter a string into a `textarea` and render it on the page.

Comment: No, it's just for the demonstration, you can go to http://babeljs.io/ and see implementation for lots of tools like gulp or grunt

Comment: you can do `require("babel-core").transform("your code");`