# How to convert string to JSX to using in React

Tags: reactjs, components, type-conversion, jsx

I have some JSX format strings which are saved into the database. Now I want to convert them to the JSX again. For example:

```
let a = "<TestComponent />"; // String is loaded from database
ReactDOM.render(
    a,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How could it be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering a string as React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471869/rendering-a-string-as-react-component)

Comment: That post asks "how do I take a string and render it as content?" while this posts asks "how do I take a string and render it as the component itself?" Not a dupe (of that one, anyway).

Comment: Googled "react parse jsx" and got https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser

Answer (score 1):

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this:

```
let a = "<TestComponent />"; // String is loaded from database
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: a};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  a,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: No Use. This approach doesn't work. Instead, it gives below: `<testcomponent></testcomponent>`