# Getting React JSX through API

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a pretty interesting question.

**Can you get a full React Element through an API call?**

Example of API response:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
   <Text>
      Hello
   </Hello>
</View>
```

Can this response be saved in a variable and used in the final `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data you get from an API call to create a function that returns a component like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const TestComponent = ({ words }) => {
    return (
      <Text>{words}</Text>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TestComponent words={"Hello World"}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you.
But my question is if my API returns a full JSX like: <View><Text>Hello</Text><View>. Somehow writing that I realise that my API will return this as String and can't really transform it to a React element. Is it true?

Comment: Try taking a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108640/how-to-convert-string-to-jsx-in-react-native

Comment: thank you for the topic, sure it's a start