# Render string as JSX in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emojione

Change this

```
"<img class="emojione" alt="" title=":flag_gb:"
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.0/png/32/1f1ec-1f1e7.png"/>"
```

to

```
<img class="emojione" alt="" title=":flag_gb:"
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.0/png/32/1f1ec-1f1e7.png"/>
```

I am using emojione in reactjs project and want to use in JSX like

```
<div>
    <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":flag_gb:"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.0/png/32/1f1ec-1f1e7.png"/>
</div>
```

**Presently, it is displaying as string inside html**

Comment: No it is a different case

Comment: @avinash Why? You want to remove the double quotes on the very beginning and on the very end and that's what the linked question is all about.

Comment: @CodeF0x, to display inside html <div><img /></div>

Comment: @avinash I am sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Can you edit your question and provide more detail?

Comment: @CodeF0x i have added some info , please check

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around your `<img>` tag at first? Don't get it.

Comment: @iArcadia let flag = emojione.shortnameToImage(":flag_gb:"); Here, emojione gives data in string

Comment: And with `emojione.shortnameToImage(":flag_gb:").replace(/"(.+)"/, '$1')`?

Comment: Or `flag = flag.substring(1, (flag.length - 1))` maybe.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your original issue is that the value is rendered as string instead of an element in React

You can use the JSX attribute `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Example :

```
render() {
   str = '<img class="emojione" alt="" title=":flag_gb:" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.0/png/32/1f1ec-1f1e7.png"/>'
   return( <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: str}}></div> )
}
```

Original SO Answer refer - [ [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx) ]

Comment: thanks, it is working with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove some characters from the start and end of a string in JS, you can use the `trim2()` function from the following example:

```
<script>
function trim2(str, chr) {
  var rgxtrim = (!chr) ? new RegExp('^\\s+|\\s+$', 'g') : new RegExp('^'+chr+'+|'+chr+'+$', 'g');
  return str.replace(rgxtrim, '');
}

var str ='"<img class="emojione" alt="????" title=":flag_gb:"src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.0/png/32/1f1ec-1f1e7.png"/>"';

let s2 = trim2(str, '"');
alert(s2);
</script>
```

- Source: https://coursesweb.net/javascript/trim-rtrim-ltrim-javascript_cs

Comment: even if the leading quotes are removed, it doesn't convert the string into JSX and does not solve the original problem.