# Replace a string to JSX Tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a string like it

```
let str = "You would get items\nwhich value about **$50**\nif you **pre-booked** it!"
```

I would like to replace `\n` to`<br/>` and I achieved it with the below code.

```
str.split('\n').map((line)=>(<span>{line}<br/></span>)
```

**What I achieved**

```
<span>You would get items<br/></span>
<span>which value about $50<br/></span>
<span>if you pre-booked it!</span>
```

And now, I want to emphasize some words like this.

**What I expect**

```
<span>You would get items<br/></span>
<span>which value about <b>$50</b><span>
<span>if you <b>pre-booked</b> it!</span>
```

I want to use like the below it.

```
const TextFormat = ({text}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {
      text.split('\n').map((line, i) => (<span key={i}>{line}<br/></span>)
    }
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36104302/218196)

Comment: This is more like a question for the correct regex replacement pattern.

Comment: @xDreamCoding but I want to return `jsx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your first `map`, you can split the line by those specific keyword. When you include a capturing group in the regex to `split`, the captured substring will be included in the result array, so you can do something like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  {
    str.split('\n').map(line => (
      <span>
        {line.split(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/).map((s, i) => i % 2 ? (<b>{s}</b>) : s)}
        <br/>
      </span>
    ))
  }
</React.Fragment>
```

This looks like markdown. You should also consider using a markdown plugin like [`react-markdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) to make potentially your life easier.

Comment: it shoud be generic not only `\$50|pre-booked)/` but any word between ** word **

Comment: @G.aziz I see. I've updated my answer to reflect the new requirements.

Comment: It is exactly what I found.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "You would get items\nwhich value about **$50**\nif you **pre-booked** it!"

const res = str.split('\n').map(line =>

  `<span>  ${line.replace(/\*\*(.*?).\*\*/,match => `<b>${match.substring(2, match.length - 2 )}</b>`)} <br/> </span>`
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry. I want `jsx`, not `string`

Comment: for jsx just replace ${} with {} and remove quotes

Comment: it is too close... but I can get a `string` like `<b>something</b>`

Comment: Just some friendly feed back: your regex pattern is a very odd. `[**]` is the same as `[*]` and `.*.` is the same as `.+`. In other words, your pattern matches a `*` followed by any number of characters and another `*` (e.g. `*foo* bar *baz*` becomes `<b> foo bar baz</b>`). Also, I'd recommend using a capturing group to include only the parts you care about inside the result rather than making a second pass through to remove the `*` characters.