# How to convert string of JSX to object of JSX?

Tags: jsx

I am making my own *Virtual DOM*. 
I have a function that gets the string of **HTML** and returns the string of **JSX**.
Аfter that I need to convert this **string of JSX** to **object of JSX** for comparison.

```
let htmlStr = '<div><div>Section 1</div><div>Section 2</div><div>Section 3</div></div>';
let jsxStr = convertHTMLtoJSX(oldMarkupStr);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058774/7480771) in the linked question, you could use NOT RECOMMENDED jsx property called: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, then your function would look like this, considering your project supports `jsx`:

```js
function convertHTMLtoJSX(jsxString) {
    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: jsxString}}></div>);
}
```