# Is it possible to dynamically construct JSX from javascript strings in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'd like to do something like the following (but with `str` actually determined dynamically):

```
let str = "I like to drive my car fast";
str = str.replace("car", "<Text style={styles.red}>red car</Text>");

return (
  <Text>{str}</Text>
);
```

Is there anyway to insert JSX into other JSX using strings?

edit: and I'd like to avoid doing it via determining the index position of 'car' and then splitting it all up into parts and reconstructing by concatenating JSX fragments.

edit2: Just to be a bit more clear, what I want to do is dynamically read a string like "I like #pizza very much", identify the tag, and output the string with #pizza in blue (i.e. like a tag on twitter etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx

Comment: That question is react, this is react native :)

Answer (score 1):

no, it is not possible with React Native at the moment, yes many people suggested `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it won't work because it is not html under the hood. You can even look at props of the most common component [View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view), it doesn't have anything closely similar to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change dynamically specify the field you want to change in a variable with can be changed later and split the text.

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/bdMxu7H_7

Check following example:

```
const text = 'I like to drive my car fast';
const replaceText = 'my car';
const replace = 'car';

export default function App() {
  const t = text.split(replace);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>{t[0]} <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{replaceText}</Text> {t[1]}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it without splitting the string up, but I see this might be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, please:

```js
let str = "I like to drive my car fast";

const arr = str.split(' ');
const reducer = (acc, cur, index) => {
    let previousVal = acc[acc.length - 1];
    if (
        previousVal &&
        previousVal.startsWith('car')
    ) {
        acc[acc.length - 1] = previousVal + ' ' + cur;
    } else {
        acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
};

const text = arr.reduce(reducer, []);

return (
    <Text>
        {text.map((text) => {
            if (text.startsWith('car')) {
                return (
                    <Text style={styles.red}>
                        {text.replaceAll('car', 'red car')}{' '}
                    </Text>
                );
            }
            return `${text} `;
        })}
    </Text>
);
```

Comment: It's not HTML.  It's React Native.

Comment: Sorry, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Why not 2 text elements?

```
<Text>I like to drive my <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{carVar}</Text></Text>
```

Comment: See my edit2.  I think that might make it a bit clearer.

Comment: if you want the color to be a variable, just change my example of 'red' to this colour variable you want. In your second edit you know that you want it blue, then just set it as blue.

Comment: You're misunderstanding.  The whole string "I like to drive my (red) car" is dynamic.  I can't hard code it as JSX.

Comment: I see what you mean now my bad, I'll have a think for you, however using any sort of string to element evaluating is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this is perhaps not the most efficient way, but it does work.  I split the string up into its component words with
`str.split(" ")`
Then iterated through the created array to check whether a word started with `#`, `@`, or a link.

```
function compose(post) {
    let str = "";
    let blnFlag = false;
    let arrWords = [];
    let arrJSX = [];
    let array = post.split(/\s/);

    for (let word of array) {
        if (/^#.+/i.test(word)) { arrWords.push( {text: word, type: "tag"} ); } 
        else if (/^@.+/i.test(word)) { arrWords.push( {text: word, type: "mention"} ); }
        else if (/^(http|www).+/i.test(word)) { arrWords.push( {text: word, type: "link"} );} 
        else { arrWords.push( {text: word, type: "plain"} ); }
    }

    for (let word of arrWords) {
        if (word.type === "plain") {
            str += word.text + " ";
        } else {
            blnFlag = true;
            if(str) {
                arrJSX.push(<Text>{str}</Text>);
                str = "";
            }
            switch(word.type) {
                case "tag":
                    arrJSX.push(<Text style={styles.tags_mentions_links}>{word.text + " "}</Text>);
                    break;
                case "mention":
                    arrJSX.push(<Text style={styles.tags_mentions_links}>{word.text + " "}</Text>);
                    break;
                case "link":
                    arrJSX.push(<Text style={styles.tags_mentions_links} onPress={() => {Linking.openURL(word.text)}}>{word.text + " "}</Text>);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!blnFlag) {
        arrJSX.push(<Text>{str}</Text>);
    }  

    return arrJSX;
}
```

Returning an array of JSX to the parent component allows you to `map` the array and output JSX directly

```
function Child(props) {
    let arrJSX = Util.compose(props.info.body);
    
    return (<P text=
              {arrJSX.map((jsx, index) => {
                  return(<Text key={index}>{jsx}</Text>)
              })}
            />)
}
```