# How to bold specific text in a string in a React.js app

Tags: reactjs, regex

I have a React.js app with a search bar which is similar to, i.e., Google. A user can type some text into an input field, and matching data is fetched and displayed in a dropdown menu below the input.

My issue: I want to bold certain words that are shown in my dropdown - specifically the words in the string that the user has **not** typed into the input field themselves.

So, for instance, if a user types in the search bar "blue", below it will display all data in the DB which contains the word "blue" i.e. "blue shoes" or "blue sky". I want it that the word that is **not** typed into the searchbar to be bolded --> sky or shoes

My makeBold function does not work because a) it displays on the browser as `<b>blue</b> sky` rather than actually bolded; b) it would bold the keyword the user typed in rather than the other words)

** `keyword` is passed to this component by the parent, it contains the text
the user has written in the input field

** `searchResults` contains the list of fetched search results passed as an
array of objects

```
const SearchResults = ({ keyword, searchResults }) => {
  
   const showDropdown = () => {
    return searchResults.map((item) => {
      if (item.term.includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
        return (
          <div key={item.term}>
            <ul>
              <li className="input-fields search-results">
                {makeBold(item.searchterm)} ({item.nrResults})
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  };

  const makeBold = (input) => {
      var re = new RegExp(keyword, 'g')
      return (
          input.replace(re, '<b>'+keyword+ '</b>')
      )
  }

  return <div>{keyword ? showDropdown () : null}</div>;
};
```

So my question is how to bold specific text in my string which has **not** typed into the input field?
Thanks!

Comment: What if you bold everything by default and un-bold the matched search term?

Comment: A possibility but the line `item.replace(re, '<b>'+keyword+ '</b>')` does not actually work. It displays on the browser as `<b>blue</b> sky`

Comment: It sounds like whatever code is consuming `makeBold` assumes the data cannot be trusted and is converting special chars to entities for literal output in the browser. Instead of a returning a string you could try returning a JDOM object instead or fix the consumer of `makeBold`. Regardless, it is impossible for me to guess how to fix your code without seeing more of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Sample code below. This is what it does.

1. Make all text bold via CSS
2. Our keyword is wrapped in a `i` tag. This is rendered with normal font weight via a CSS rule.

**Please note** that below is a code sample to be used in react context/OP application, this will not work in this site.

```js
const makeBold = (item, keyword) => {
      var re = new RegExp(keyword, 'g')
      return (
          item.replace(re, '<i>'+keyword+ '</i>')
      )
  }
  
  console.log(makeBold('blue shoes', 'blue'));
```

```css
.text-bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.text-bold i {
 font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div className="text-bold">
   <ul>
      <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: makeBold(item, 'blue')}} />
   </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of dangouresly setting the html you can also use the package [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser). This avoids the use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Then the code would look like

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

<div className="text-bold">
       <ul>
          <li> {ReactHtmlParser(makeBold(item, 'blue')) }
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Its dangerous thats the reason its named like that. Please check the link XSS link under https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml   Part 2: We can either do it as per the link you provided or use a package which does that for you (DRY approach)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `copy+paste?` can u show a website where you see the above code other than react functions!. `So providing insecure code using a rebranded innerHTML` dangerouslySetInnerHTML is there for a reason(and its not exactly equal to innerHTML), otherwise React wont even have it. If you are talking about the npm package, thats not the rebrand of innerHTML, please check the package source in github before commenting. If you have a different approach(other than the 2 mentioned in above answer) please provide that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute.

But as its name suggests, it can be dangerous. If this input is coming from an external source then you have to make sure that it does not contain any unwanted scripts or links!

```
return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: item.replace(re, '<b>' + keyword + '</b>')
  }} />
)
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It's named dangerous because they wanted to make it clear that it's the developer's job to make sure the inserted html is safe. The answer you linked is a good way to make it safe.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here are my comments in an answer form.

Your problem is basically how to convert a String to JSX. Have a look at [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx) - you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Be aware that the solution there is vulnerable to XSS attacks though so make sure you trust your input.

An example of how to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is below:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  const keyword = "beans";

  const makeBold = item => {
    const re = new RegExp(keyword, "g");
    return item.replace(re, "<b>" + keyword + "</b>");
  };
  
  const items = [
    "I really like beans",
    "I really don't like beans",
    "I really like eggs"
  ]

  ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <ul>
      {
        items.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <li
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: makeBold(item) }}
              key={i}
            />
          )
        })
      }
    </ul>
  </div>, document.getElementById('root') );

</script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this work  for /\d{1,2}(.\d)*%/, it could work for u

```js
const MainMessage = ({ msg }) => {
  const newExpresion = [];
  const newMsg = msg.split(/\s/);
  
  newExpresion.push("");
  let i = 0;
  newMsg.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.match(/\d{1,2}(.\d)*%/)) {
      newExpresion.push(<b> {element} </b>);
      newExpresion.push("");
      i += 2;
    } else {
      newExpresion[i] = `${newExpresion[i]} ${element}`;
    }
  });
  return <div>{newExpresion.map((item) => item)}</div>;
};
```