# Convert a string to a react component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, jsx

I have a string that's a react component coming back from an API request. Unfortunately, I have no control over how the data gets returned, so it comes back like

```
`<Sphere><meshBasicMaterial attach='material' color='pink' /></Sphere>`
```

All I want to do is be able to render the above in a react component, but because it's a string I can't. Ideally, without using any external libraries to convert it.

Am I missing something simple here? Any information helps!

```
// string = "<Sphere><meshBasicMaterial attach='material' color='pink' /></Sphere>"

function Scene({string}) {

  // const MyComponent = string

  const MyComponent = () => { return (string) }

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas>
        <MyComponent />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

Note - I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx) StackOverflow question, but is not a solution in my case due to extensive non-HTML tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx)

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç I found those solutions, but unfortunately doesn't help because I'm trying to render a react component and not HTML as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't understand jsx, so you'll need to compile it somehow. Normally that is done on the server, but if you need to do it on the client then you can use the Babel standalone js bundle: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx

Note: since your string contains non-HTML tags, using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not a solution in your case. Also note that you may still need to import the components mentioned in the string (in the example, the `Sphere` component).

Comment: My application is built using Meteor & React. Currently, all the components are rendered client side. I suppose I can reconfigure the application to SSR.

Comment: Meteor, good. I happen to know Meteor pretty well. And no, we are talking about different things here. Yes, the react templates are rendered client side, but the JSX is translated into "pure" react code server-side. SSR would be if all the client would get was a static HTML file that already has all the data filled in as well.

Comment: Right - I'm following. I found react-live that takes in react code and provides an editor as well as displays your code. This is what I was looking for . React-live uses Buble as opposed to Babel for transpiling, but it's lightning-fast and light-weight so I'm good with it. Thanks for your wisdom, Christian!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below example, basically, you need to evaluate string to element, we can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```js
const htmlStringElem = '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';

const App = () => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlStringElem }} />
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please see running code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-forked-gqgz2?file=/index.js

Comment: This is not a solution if you have non-HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with `React`, you can use Parse.

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";


const App = () => (
   {parse(<Sphere><meshBasicMaterial attach='material' color='pink' /></Sphere>)}

);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

This is an easy and safe way to achieve this.