# How to render string including JSX component with PascalCase in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app, receiving the blog post data from external cms. The data is raw HTML as a string, like this:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<img src="example.com/felan.jpg">
<p>some text</p>
<img src"example.com/another.jpg">
...
```

Now, I want to replace `img` HTML tag with a jsx component called `Img` (with capital I).
I do it with:

```
let postContentOptimized = post.replace("img", "Img");

<article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postContentOptimized }} />
```

But it automatically converts `Img` to `img` (changes PascalCase).

I also tried with other component names, and it throws this error:

```
React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
```

Comment: You cannot do this. HTML and JSX are not interchangeable like this. Setting the inner HTML will do just that: set HTML, it will not treat it as JSX, PascalCase or not.

Comment: So how should I parse a string including jsx tags?

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx

Answer (score 0):

I found a package called `react-jsx-parser`.
Its documentation isn't straightforward, thus I skipped it the first time I found it.
Here's how to do it if you're confused like me:

```
<JsxParser components={{ components used in your string }} jsx={the string you want to parse} />
```

example:

```
<JsxParser components={{ Img }} jsx="<Img src="hello.png /><p>hello</p>" />
```