# Convert React components String to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a string of React components .

```
//X.jsx
import "./x.css"
const X =({x}) =><div className={"x"} >{x}</div>

//Y.jsx
import "./y.css"
const Y =({y}) =><div className={"y"} >{y}</div>

`<X x={"x"}/> <Y x={"y"}/>`
```

I want to convert it to jsx how to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx)

Comment: do u use a compiler like `babel`? Did you create your app with `npx create-react-app my-app`?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you have a string of Components?

Comment: @Sysix create-react-app my-app

Comment: @pilchard there can be many components in a string

Comment: But why do you have a string to begin with? You've declared some components, what situation is leading you to need to use a string to utilize them?

Comment: @pilchard    I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845242/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dynamic-page-using-form-and-react-components) yesterday and I want to do about the same

Comment: @Squanchy You mean this string is user input (from a textarea) and you want to display it back to them? Also to other users? Notice that JSX is basically JS code, you'd have to transpile and `eval` it.

Comment: @Bergi I don’t know if it’s right to use it. We need to think about it, but Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Squanchy The default answer would be that no, it's not right. `eval` is dangerous, and strings of code are bad. But we can't give more advice if you don't tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Bergi here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-lewin-rxdkt?file=/src/App.js:1592-1601) to an example what i want but i'm not sure about the JsxParser package.

Answer (score -1):

I think the example you provided would inject the CSS declarations into the classname, no? That doesn't seem like what you want. [Maybe consult this page and explore an avenue](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/) where you are importing the css in as a module to the given component and adding the relevant classname to it from the file.