# New line in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, newline

I'm trying to send following code to a child component in React js:

```
{
    carPhoto: "../../images/small-logo.jpg",
    make: "Mercedes",
    price: "€20000",
    desc: "Vivamus gravida magna massa in cursus mi"
}
```

Now I'm trying to split **desc** in two lines. 
I tried with **\n**, **\r**, **\r\n**

```
desc: "Vivamus gravida magna<br /> massa in cursus mi"
desc: "Vivamus gravida magna\nmassa in cursus mi"
desc: "Vivamus gravida magna\r\nmassa in cursus mi"
```

But nothing worked. Any advice?

Comment: use \n and set white-space: pre; in css?

Answer (score 7):

```
<span>
 Example #1: <br /> newline
</span>
<span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
 {"Example #2: \r new line or \u000A new line"}
</span>
{/* do not forget add style { white-space: pre-wrap } */}
<Example3 text={"Example #2: \r new line or \u000A new line"} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to do white space or new line in react is create module with it like this: (and do not forget add white-space: pre or pre-wrap; for container)

```
// htmlCodes.js
export const nbsp = '\u00A0';
export const breakline = '\u000A';
```

and then use it in component or strings:

```
// MyComponent.jsx
import {nbsp, breakline} from './htmlCodes';

const myString = `one{nbsp}two{breakline}`;

const MyComponent = () => {
  <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
    first{nbsp}second{breakline}third
  </div>
}
```

the best way, create component Text and use their together:

```
// Text.jsx
export const Text = (children) => {
  <span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
    {children}
  </span> 
}

// MyComponent.jsx
import {nbsp, breakline} from './htmlCodes';
import {Text} from './Text.jsx';

const MyComponent = () => {
  <div>
   <Text>one{nbsp}two{breakline}three</Text>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very simple way with very simple component with simplest `html` output**

and you can use it like prop

```
<TravelCard
      text={<BreakString
            text={"7 days \n Friends Reunion\n Historic, Touristy"} >}
/>
```

**or**

```
<p>
   <BreakString
      text={"7 days \n Friends Reunion\n Historic, Touristy"} />
</p>
```

component you should create:

```
const BreakString = ({ text }) => {
  const strArr = text.split("\n");
  return (
    <>
      {strArr.map((str, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          {str}
          {index !== str.length - 1 && <br />}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

**output**

```
<p>7 days <br> Friends Reunion<br> Historic, Touristy<br></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can either use CSS, as suggested in the comments. Or you can [dangerously set inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html) using the `<br/>` tag:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.desc}} />
```

It's important to note that this approach is XSS-prone, thus the name.

You can read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html