# How to add line break into JS object that is passed as a property?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use a JS helper file that consists of objects that are passed into a function that renders it. However, the \n doesn't work and I am not sure how to add line breaks. This is my helper list.

```
export const TweetList = [
{
    link: 'https://twitter.com/JayWuzer/status/1553804606265651200',
    tweet: "Being your full authentic self is a life hack. \n The ones who don't vibe with you will naturally be repulsed, and the ones who do vibe with you will naturally be drawn to you. \n Saves a LOT of time and heartache.",
    date: 7/31/2022
},
```

This is my function that renders the text.
[Could not format properly so I used an image instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouBNp.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New line in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238523/new-line-in-react)

Comment: Could you do something like `TweetList[0].tweet = TweetList[0].tweet.replaceAll("\n","<br>")` to replace all newlines with the HTML line break entity?

Answer (score 3):

you need to add styles

```
whiteSpace: 'pre-line'
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat css option. I didn't realize it allowed for `\n` to be treated as `<br>` , I'll definitely be using this at some point!