# I am getting HTML from the backend . How can I put it in <Text> in react native

Tags: html, reactjs, text, react-native, jsx

(Current Output):

> Coming Soon Shortly  `<br />` Coming Soon Shortly `<br />` Coming Soon Shortly

When I put in `<Text>` , it shows `<br>` tag as it is , instead of going to the next line

(Expected output):

Coming Soon Shortly

Coming Soon Shortly

Coming Soon Shortly

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you meant `<textarea>`. To put a new line use:

```
&#13;&#10;
```

Example:

```
<textarea>Hello World&#13;&#10;How are you?</textarea>
```

Comment: I am getting <br> tag along with some text from API . 
I want to break the line when <br> tag comes , but instead,  it showing <br> tag in output. 

Output in emulator comes out to be
Coming Soon Shortly < br > Coming Soon Shortly< br >Coming Soon Shortly" 

instead of :
Coming Soon Shortly 
Coming Soon Shortly
Coming Soon Shortly"

Comment: You'll have to use java script to replace the <br> with &#13;&#10; or use a backend to do that with php before it populates the text area.

Comment: I have tried using it 
<Text>Hello World &#13;&#10; How are you?</Text> 
still it is showing the text in same line . 
what do you suggest now ?

Comment: @rajat44 There is no such thing as `<Text>`. So what did you mean instead? I guess that Tim's assumption is not correct, so what is it? Did you mean SVG `<text>`? If so, the question should have been tagged [svg], and you should have written `<text>` in lowercase, since svg is case sensitive. Or are you just inventing new tag names as you go along?

Comment: @MrLister There is a <Text> tag in **"REACT NATIVE"**. I don't know why you and Tim are not getting it. 
if I put a HTML tag in my <Text> it is getting printed as a text . 
for ex - 
<Text>hi my name is <br/> Rajat <br/> Gupta </Text>

Expected output is:-  hi my name is
(next line)Rajat 
(next line)Gupta

but it is coming as :-
hi my name is <br/> Rajat <br/> Gupta. 

I hope you get it now .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this plugin: https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text

then try to define your own Regex pattern (as @farwayer sample)

Answer (score 0):

For `reactJs` you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property to set content as `HTML`.

Comment: What is this ? 
where can I read about this ? and what does it do

Comment: Please check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is for reactjs _not_ react native

Answer (score 0):

```
text = text.replace(/<\s*br\s*\/*\s*>/gi, '\n')
```

Comment: are you sure '\n' will not get printed and will work as next line?

Comment: Yes `<Text>`interprets '\n' (hex 0x0A) as new line delimiter.