# How can I pass HTML as props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an HTML tag value in my state variable as

```
this.state = {
    value: '<p>This is a paragraph</p>'
}
```

I want to display this HTML content in my child component. I'm trying to do as

```
<Childcomponent value={this.state.value} />
```

So that i can use the `props` to access the value inside the child component. 
My child component is

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
    )
}
```

But this produces some errors. How can I fix this? Is there any other solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Comment: Show `Childcomponent ` code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs convert to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html)

Comment: @ssk Please check the edits

Answer (score 5):

you should use jsx for this,

```
const someHtml = (<p>This is a paragraph</p>)
```

and then pass it to your child component as prop like this (prop type is node)

```
<Childcomponent value={someHtml} />
```

and render it like any other variable `{value}` in the child component

Comment: I'm dynamically setting the state value. How can i do that?

Comment: you can use the state also for creating the html like so 
const someHtml = (<p>{this.state.value}</p>)

Comment: In the console of parent component when i get like`{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type:'p'}` format i get the child component correctly. But when i get the console with pure html like `<p>This is paragraph</p>` I get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend doing it, but if you know what you are doing, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.
So, your ChildComponent should be something like

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={props.value} />
}
```

But, like I said, I don't recommend doing it, as it can be vulnerable for XSS attacks. 
You can find more info in [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: In the console of parent component when i get like`{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type:'p'}` format i get the child component correctly. But when i get the console with pure html like `<p>This is paragraph</p>` I get the error.

Comment: Is there any method to change the HTML to react element? Whan I set the state i get only as HTML

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you describe your use case? I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with passing html as prop. 

Usually you don't set the state to html, rather have html as component, and pass data to it, like Eliran's answer. 
without understanding what you are trying to accomplish it is hard to give proper answer, but this answer does exactly what you are asking in the question

Comment: Mine is a drag and drop functionality. When I drag and drop a text or paragraph I just want to send that `<p>` to the child component which populates the dropped area.

Comment: I can't tell you all details how to implement it in a comment here, but you definitely should not pass around html elements as string values in that use case.
What you can do is to have components that are draggable and based on drag and drop events save it in state(not string, but component itself). Later, you can use that state value to render that component.  You can search on internet for react drag and drop, there is even library for that

Answer (score 3):

I think the approach is wrong here.

Firstly, state should be reserved for values that change or data coming in from an API.  I would not say that a html snippet should be part of an applications state.

Eliran suggests an approach, but again whereby the child component is expecting a prop called value.

There is also another way, which is 'children' where you can squirt in html to a child component.

E.g.

```
<Childcomponent value={somePropToPassDown}>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</ChildComponent>
```

and in the component itself....

```
const ChildComponent= (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Have a read of this article on [React Children](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891) which explains in more detail

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the value as string instead you can set the value dynamically wrapping the text with a html element.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  value: ''
 }
}

componentDidMount = async () => {
 this.setState({
  value: <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 })
}
```

By this way you can set and render the html element dynamically.

You can also use dangerously set inner html. Here is the link for the reference, https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html.