# Convert fetched data into HTML in React

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg

I am fetchin data and one of the data I fetch looks like this

```
<p><strong>This is my first content and it is supposed to represent my index.</strong></p>
```

this is an wysiwyg output on a server and while I am trying to bring to my screen, I get it exactly as it is.

[image]

Please tell me how I can import this data as html into my page.

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html/27938353#27938353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## dangerouslySetInnerHTML

from the docs here's an example

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Like the name suggests this is dangerous if you dont have the html properly vetted.

For detail information on this please read the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your data in HTML by creating the reference to that element and just set `innerHTML` property to your fetched data that contains HTML in its value.

This snippet gives you more idea:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    // create reference
    this.titleDiv = React.createRef();

    // this can be whatever you get HTML data from
    this.state ={
      testHTML: "<h1>Test HTML Text</h1>"
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = this.titleDiv.current;
    element.innerHTML = this.state.testHTML;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // define reference for where you want to set HTML
      <div ref={this.titleDiv}></div>
    )
  }
```

you can deep dive into `ref` in react.js here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html