# React: Change string containing HTML to real HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

I saved some editor output to the database.  The output containing the html code is converted to a string like this:

```html
"<p><span style='color: rgb(43, 51, 94); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px;'>Some Content...</span>&nbsp;v</p>"
```

I got the value from the database as an object and used it in React:

```html
<div className="content-main">
    {data.content}
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

I did a lot of searching, but I didn't find any solution or my search was wrong.  What is the correct way to convert this value to HTML in React?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout react-html-parser here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser.

Once installed this is all you have to do :

```
<div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` method. So in your case:

```
const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  function createMarkup() {
    return {__html: data.content};
  }

  return <div className="content-main" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

But, as it says [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), You should be aware of the potential XSS risks:

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to
>   inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS)
>   attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type
>   out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to
>   remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerHTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data.content">
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, React escapes the HTML to prevent XSS (Cross-site scripting). If you really want to render HTML, you can use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML property:

< td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.actions}}  />

React forces this intentionally-cumbersome syntax so that you don't accidentally render text as HTML and introduce XSS bugs.

Already answered 
[Reactjs convert html string to jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx)