# How do i display formatted html code stored in javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a react application that has a blogging function and I need it to properly display my HTML content stored in my javascript object.
This is what I mean:

```js
const blog = {
  name: "post1",
  content: "<p>This is my first blog post</p>",
}
```

I have an object that stores the blog content and when I make a reference to the object I need it to render properly in the DOM as a paragraph, but instead, it renders with the tags displaying in react, please how do i fix it and make the content render as a DOM element

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx

Comment: assuming you're using JSX in the rest of your app, just use that here instead of a string: `content: (<p>This is my first blog post</p>)`. This will be transpiled into a JS object (the output of `React.createElement`), rather than the string you now have.

Comment: DangerouslySetInnerHTML works perfectly...thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop on a host component like a `div`:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: blog.content } } />
```

See also:
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml