# Create snippet with multiply feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet, vscode-snippets

I want to recreate this multiply effect in my own snippet, but for a React component, as featured here:

[image: Emmet in vscode]

---

Typing `[componentName]*3` will create:

```
<ComponentName/>
<ComponentName/>
<ComponentName/>
```

If possible it would ideal if typing `[componentName],*3` would create:

```
<ComponentName/>,
<ComponentName/>,
<ComponentName/> //note the missing comma here!
```

---

I was trying to figure this out from the Emmet and snippet documentation on the VSCode site but was unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Comment: Comma is not allowed in Emmet abbreviations. Why would you need a comma after tag?

Comment: You should show how you got `[componentName]*3` to expand to what you have already.

Comment: @Mark, that's part of the issue, I don't know how to do that in Emmet.

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok I'm passing components as `props` using [mixed arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx) of HTML components and strings. Do you have a suggestion about how to do it differently?

Comment: @Jack it requires custom support from Emmet side to properly support this feature. It might be added in future